# Finding duplicate values in a SQL table

Tags: sql, duplicates

It's easy to find duplicates with one field:

```
SELECT email, COUNT(email) 
FROM users
GROUP BY email
HAVING COUNT(email) > 1
```

So if we have a table

```
ID   NAME   EMAIL
1    John   asd@asd.com
2    Sam    asd@asd.com
3    Tom    asd@asd.com
4    Bob    bob@asd.com
5    Tom    asd@asd.com
```

This query will give us John, Sam, Tom, Tom because they all have the same `email`.

However, what I want is to get duplicates with the same `email` **and** `name`.

That is, I want to get "Tom", "Tom".

The reason I need this: I made a mistake, and allowed inserting duplicate `name` and `email` values. Now I need to remove/change the duplicates, so I need to *find* them first.

Comment: I don't think it would let you select name in your first sample since it's not in an aggregate function.  "What is the count of matching email addresses and their name" is some tricky logic...

Comment: Found that this doesn't work with MSSQL server because of the `name` field in the SELECT.

Answer (score 3697, accepted):

```
SELECT
    name, email, COUNT(*)
FROM
    users
GROUP BY
    name, email
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) > 1
```

Simply group on both of the columns.

Note: the older ANSI standard is to have all non-aggregated columns in the GROUP BY but this has changed with the idea of ["functional dependency"](https://blog.jooq.org/2015/12/10/sql-group-by-and-functional-dependencies-a-very-useful-feature/):

> In relational database theory, a functional dependency is a constraint between two sets of attributes in a relation from a database. In other words, functional dependency is a constraint that describes the relationship between attributes in a relation.

Support is not consistent:

- Recent PostgreSQL [supports it](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-GROUPBY).
- SQL Server (as at SQL Server 2017) still requires all non-aggregated columns in the GROUP BY.
- MySQL is unpredictable and you need `sql_mode=only_full_group_by`:

  - [GROUP BY lname ORDER BY showing wrong results](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10894820/27535);
  - [Which is the least expensive aggregate function in the absence of ANY()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6060241/which-is-the-least-expensive-aggregate-function-in-the-absence-of-any/6060414#6060414) (see comments in accepted answer).
- Oracle isn't mainstream enough (warning: humour, I don't know about Oracle).

Comment: @webXL WHERE works with single record HAVING works with group

Comment: @gbn Is it possible to include the Id in the results? Then it would be easier to delete those duplicates afterwards.

Comment: @user797717: you'd need to have MIN(ID) and then delete for ID values not in the last if MIN(ID) values

Comment: What about cases where any of the columns have null values?

Comment: @AnkitDhingra The NULL values are grouped like "bob" or "gbn". No special behaviour

Comment: Thanks so much for this, and yes it does work in Oracle, though I needed uniqueness of the condition, so rather than `>1` `=1`

Comment: To find duplicate value count: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table where value = 'value1'

Comment: @gbn . In this way of writing query we are able to find the duplicate name and email in users table . what if we want to find the IDs of users who have duplicate name and email id . Can you please write a query to find IDs of users who have duplicate name and email id  ?

Comment: I seriously come back to this post at least twice a week.  going to have to start using my memory more.  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for it. I need to find duplicate row that having several same fields value.

Comment: what if I want the total amount of the result entries ?

Comment: @gbn can you give some example of the question of @user797717?

Comment: See @gaurav-singh's answer below with `row_number()` to see whole record (all fields).

Comment: @BillNaylor The functional dependency is not implemented by Oracle 19: if you write `group by id` instead of `group by name, email` it is rejected by Oracle. This is actually explained in the blog post linked, so I don't know why Andry said he didn't know for Oracle.

Answer (score 442):

Try this:

```
declare @YourTable table (id int, name varchar(10), email varchar(50))

INSERT @YourTable VALUES (1,'John','John-email')
INSERT @YourTable VALUES (2,'John','John-email')
INSERT @YourTable VALUES (3,'fred','John-email')
INSERT @YourTable VALUES (4,'fred','fred-email')
INSERT @YourTable VALUES (5,'sam','sam-email')
INSERT @YourTable VALUES (6,'sam','sam-email')

SELECT
    name,email, COUNT(*) AS CountOf
    FROM @YourTable
    GROUP BY name,email
    HAVING COUNT(*)>1
```

OUTPUT:

```
name       email       CountOf
---------- ----------- -----------
John       John-email  2
sam        sam-email   2

(2 row(s) affected)
```

If you want the IDs of the dups use this:

```
SELECT
    y.id,y.name,y.email
    FROM @YourTable y
        INNER JOIN (SELECT
                        name,email, COUNT(*) AS CountOf
                        FROM @YourTable
                        GROUP BY name,email
                        HAVING COUNT(*)>1
                    ) dt ON y.name=dt.name AND y.email=dt.email
```

OUTPUT:

```
id          name       email
----------- ---------- ------------
1           John       John-email
2           John       John-email
5           sam        sam-email
6           sam        sam-email

(4 row(s) affected)
```

To delete the duplicates try:

```
DELETE d
    FROM @YourTable d
        INNER JOIN (SELECT
                        y.id,y.name,y.email,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY y.name,y.email ORDER BY y.name,y.email,y.id) AS RowRank
                        FROM @YourTable y
                            INNER JOIN (SELECT
                                            name,email, COUNT(*) AS CountOf
                                            FROM @YourTable
                                            GROUP BY name,email
                                            HAVING COUNT(*)>1
                                        ) dt ON y.name=dt.name AND y.email=dt.email
                   ) dt2 ON d.id=dt2.id
        WHERE dt2.RowRank!=1
SELECT * FROM @YourTable
```

OUTPUT:

```
id          name       email
----------- ---------- --------------
1           John       John-email
3           fred       John-email
4           fred       fred-email
5           sam        sam-email

(4 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: * Table names are case sensitivearray(3) { [0]=> string(5) "42000" [1]=> int(1064) [2]=> string(226) "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(PARTITION BY y.employee_id, y.leave_type_id ) AS RowRank ' at line 1" }

Answer (score 156):

```
SELECT name, email
FROM users
GROUP BY name, email
HAVING ( COUNT(*) > 1 )
```

Answer (score 107):

If you want to delete the duplicates, here's a much simpler way to do it than having to find even/odd rows into a triple sub-select:

```
SELECT id, name, email 
FROM users u, users u2
WHERE u.name = u2.name AND u.email = u2.email AND u.id > u2.id
```

And so to delete:

```
DELETE FROM users
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT id/*, name, email*/
    FROM users u, users u2
    WHERE u.name = u2.name AND u.email = u2.email AND u.id > u2.id
)
```

Much more easier to read and understand IMHO

**Note:** The only issue is that you have to execute the request until there is no rows deleted, since you delete only 1 of each duplicate each time

Comment: Nice and easy to read; I'd like to find a way that deleted multiple duplicate rows in one go though.

Comment: This doesn't work for me as I get `You can't specify target table 'users' for update in FROM clause`

Comment: @Whitecat seems like a simple MySQL problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4429319/you-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause

Comment: Fails for me.  I get:

"DBD::CSV::st execute failed: Use of uninitialized value $_[1] in hash element at /Users/hornenj/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.26.0/lib/site_perl/5.26.0/SQL/Eval.pm line 43"

Comment: I think that where clause should be " u.name = u2.name AND u.email = u2.email AND (u.id > u2.id OR u2.id > u.id)" isn't it?

Comment: @GiveEmTheBoot since u and u2 are the same tables, it doesn't really matter, but yeah, I guess doing `u.name = u2.name AND u.email = u2.email AND u.id <> u2.id` would work just as well

Comment: @GiveEmTheBoot your adding extra complication really. I would just keep it the way AncAinu has put it. It really doesn't matter.

Also, I just want to point out - props to AncAinu, this is really a genius explanation. If people have their tables laid out correctly with IDs generated for each record this works flawlessly. Great, and easy to read and maintain!

Answer (score 64):

In contrast to other answers you can view the *whole* records containing all columns if there are any. In the `PARTITION BY` part of [row_number](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-row_number/) function choose the desired unique/duplicit columns.

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
 SELECT a.*
 ,      Row_Number() OVER (PARTITION BY Name, Age ORDER BY Name) AS r
 FROM   Customers AS a
)       AS b
WHERE   r > 1;
```

When you want to select **ALL** duplicated records with *ALL* fields you can write it like

```sql
CREATE TABLE test (
        id      bigint GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY
,       c1      integer
,       c2      text
,       d       date DEFAULT now()
,       v       text
);

INSERT INTO test (c1, c2, v) VALUES
(1, 'a', 'Select'),
(1, 'a', 'ALL'),
(1, 'a', 'multiple'),
(1, 'a', 'records'),
(2, 'b', 'in columns'),
(2, 'b', 'c1 and c2'),
(3, 'c', '.');
SELECT * FROM test ORDER BY 1;

SELECT  *
FROM    test
WHERE   (c1, c2) IN (
 SELECT c1, c2
 FROM   test
 GROUP  BY 1,2
 HAVING count(*) > 1
)
ORDER   BY 1;
```

Tested in [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/).

Answer (score 40):

```
SELECT name, email 
FROM users
WHERE email in
    (SELECT email FROM users
    GROUP BY email 
    HAVING COUNT(*)>1)
```

Answer (score 38):

```
SELECT email, GROUP_CONCAT(id)
FROM   users
GROUP  BY email
HAVING COUNT(email) > 1;
```

Comment: Keep in mind that `GROUP_CONCAT` will stop after some predetermined length, so you might not get all the `id`s.

Answer (score 29):

This selects/deletes all duplicate records except one record from each group of duplicates. So, the delete leaves all unique records + one record from each group of the duplicates.

Select duplicates:

```
SELECT *
FROM <table>
WHERE
    id NOT IN (
        SELECT MIN(id)
        FROM table
        GROUP BY <column1>, <column2>
);
```

Delete duplicates:

```
DELETE FROM <table>
WHERE
    id NOT IN (
        SELECT MIN(id)
        FROM table
        GROUP BY <column1>, <column2>
);
```

*Be aware of larger amounts of records, it can cause performance problems.*

Comment: Error in delete query - You can't specify target table 'cities' for update in FROM clause

Comment: There is neither table 'cities' nor update clause. What do you mean? Where is an error in the delete query?

Answer (score 23):

```
WITH CTE AS
    ( SELECT Id, Name, Age,
        Comments, RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name,Age ORDER BY ccn)
    FROM ccnmaster )
select * from CTE
```

Answer (score 19):

In case you work with Oracle, this way would be preferable:

```
create table my_users(id number, name varchar2(100), email varchar2(100));

insert into my_users values (1, 'John', 'asd@asd.com');
insert into my_users values (2, 'Sam', 'asd@asd.com');
insert into my_users values (3, 'Tom', 'asd@asd.com');
insert into my_users values (4, 'Bob', 'bob@asd.com');
insert into my_users values (5, 'Tom', 'asd@asd.com');

commit;

select *
from my_users
where rowid not in (
    select min(rowid)
    from my_users
    group by name, email);
```

Answer (score 19):

Pick the solution which best fits.

```
Create table NewTable (id int, name varchar(10), email varchar(50))
INSERT  NewTable VALUES (1,'John','asd@asd.com')
INSERT  NewTable VALUES (2,'Sam','asd@asd.com')
INSERT  NewTable VALUES (3,'Tom','asd@asd.com')
INSERT  NewTable VALUES (4,'Bob','bob@asd.com')
INSERT  NewTable VALUES (5,'Tom','asd@asd.com')
```

[image]

**1. USING GROUP BY CLAUSE**

```
SELECT
    name, email, COUNT(*) AS Occurence
FROM NewTable
GROUP BY name, email
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

[image]

- The GROUP BY clause groups the rows into groups by values in
  both name and email columns.
- Then, the COUNT() function returns the number
  of occurrences of each group (name,email).
- Then, the HAVING clause keeps
  only duplicate groups, which are groups that have more than one
  occurrence.

**2. Using a CTE:**

To return the entire row for each duplicate row, join the result of the above query with the `NewTable` table using a common table expression (CTE):

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        name, email, COUNT(*) occurrences
    FROM NewTable
    GROUP BY name, email
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
SELECT 
    t1.Id, t1.name, t1.email
FROM  NewTable t1
INNER JOIN cte ON 
    cte.name = t1.name AND 
    cte.email = t1.email
ORDER BY 
    t1.name, 
    t1.email;
```

[image]

**3. Using function ROW_NUMBER()**

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT 
        name, email, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY name,email
            ORDER BY name,email) rownum
    FROM NewTable t1
) 
SELECT 
  * 
FROM cte 
WHERE rownum > 1;
```

[image]

- `ROW_NUMBER()` distributes rows of the `NewTable` table into partitions by values in the `name` and `email` columns. The duplicate rows will have repeated values in the `name` and `email` columns, but different row numbers
- Outer query removes the first row in each group.

Comment: The code in those images is redundant & the results should be text. . [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) [Why are images of text, code and mathematical expressions discouraged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/320052/266284)

Answer (score 15):

```
select name, email
, case 
when ROW_NUMBER () over (partition by name, email order by name) > 1 then 'Yes'
else 'No'
end "duplicated ?"
from users
```

Comment: Code only answers are frowned upon on Stack Overflow, could you explain why this answers the question?

Comment: @RichBenner: I didn't find the response such as, each & every row in the result and which tells us which all are duplicate rows and which are not in one glance and that to not group by, because if we want to combine this query with any other query group by is not a good option.

Comment: Adding Id to the select statement and filtering on duplicated , it give you the possibility to delete the duplicated ids and keep on of each.

Answer (score 12):

```
create table my_table(id int, name varchar(100), email varchar(100));

insert into my_table values (1, 'shekh', 'shekh@rms.com');
insert into my_table values (1, 'shekh', 'shekh@rms.com');
insert into my_table values (2, 'Aman', 'aman@rms.com');
insert into my_table values (3, 'Tom', 'tom@rms.com');
insert into my_table values (4, 'Raj', 'raj@rms.com');

Select COUNT(1) As Total_Rows from my_table 
Select Count(1) As Distinct_Rows from ( Select Distinct * from my_table) abc
```

Answer (score 12):

`SELECT id, COUNT(id) FROM table1 GROUP BY id HAVING COUNT(id)>1;`

Comment: This doesn't quite add anything to [the top answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2594855/419956), and technically doesn't even really differ from the code OP's posted in the question.

Answer (score 12):

This is the easy thing I've come up with.  It uses a common table expression (CTE) and a partition window (I think these features are in SQL 2008 and later).

This example finds all students with duplicate name and dob.  The fields you want to check for duplication go in the OVER clause.  You can include any other fields you want in the projection.

```
with cte (StudentId, Fname, LName, DOB, RowCnt)
as (
SELECT StudentId, FirstName, LastName, DateOfBirth as DOB, SUM(1) OVER (Partition By FirstName, LastName, DateOfBirth) as RowCnt
FROM tblStudent
)
SELECT * from CTE where RowCnt > 1
ORDER BY DOB, LName
```

Answer (score 11):

```
 select emp.ename, emp.empno, dept.loc 
 from emp
 inner join dept 
 on dept.deptno=emp.deptno
 inner join
    (select ename, count(*)
    from emp
    group by ename, deptno
    having count(*) > 1) t
 on emp.ename=t.ename
 order by emp.ename
```

Answer (score 10):

Either a duplicated value is repeated 2 times or greater than 2.
Just count them, not groupwise.

```
select COUNT(distinct col_01) from Table_01
```

Comment: How would this work for the question as asked? This does *not* give rows that duplicate information in multiple columns (e.g. "email" and "name") in different rows.

Answer (score 10):

```
with MyCTE
as
(
select Name,EmailId,ROW_NUMBER() over(PARTITION BY EmailId order by id) as Duplicate from [Employees]
)
select * from MyCTE where Duplicate>1
```

Answer (score 7):

```
 select * from Users a
 where exists (select * from Users b 
     where (a.name = b.name 
         or a.email = b.email)
         and a.ID != b.id)
```

If you search for duplicates who have some kind of prefix or general change like a new domain in mail then you can use replace() at these columns.

Answer (score 7):

```
SELECT * FROM users u where rowid = (select max(rowid) from users u1 where
u.email=u1.email);
```

Answer (score 6):

```sql
SELECT name, email,COUNT(email) 
FROM users 
WHERE email IN (
    SELECT email 
    FROM users 
    GROUP BY email 
    HAVING COUNT(email) > 1)
```

Comment: You can't use `COUNT` without `GROUP BY`, unless it refers to the whole table.

Comment: Without Group By you used COUNT but here i have doing a typing mistake to write COUNT

Answer (score 6):

The most important thing here is to have the fastest function. Also indices of duplicates should be identified. Self join is a good option but to have a faster function it is better to first find rows that have duplicates and then join with original table for finding id of duplicated rows. Finally order by any column except id to have duplicated rows near each other.

```
SELECT u.*
FROM users AS u
JOIN (SELECT username, email
      FROM users
      GROUP BY username, email
      HAVING COUNT(*)>1) AS w
ON u.username=w.username AND u.email=w.email
ORDER BY u.email;
```

Answer (score 3):

To delete records whose names are duplicate

```
;WITH CTE AS    
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY name) AS T FROM     @YourTable    
)
DELETE FROM CTE WHERE T > 1
```

Comment: Does it work? How comes I get this error 'relation "cte" does not exist' in Postgres?

Comment: CTE works also in postgress sql..Here is the link https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-cte/ 
You must be missing something else.

Answer (score 3):

To Check From duplicate Record in a table.

```
select * from users s 
where rowid < any 
(select rowid from users k where s.name = k.name and s.email = k.email);
```

or

```
select * from users s 
where rowid not in 
(select max(rowid) from users k where s.name = k.name and s.email = k.email);
```

To Delete the duplicate record in a table.

```
delete from users s 
where rowid < any 
(select rowid from users k where s.name = k.name and s.email = k.email);
```

or

```
delete from users s 
where rowid not in 
(select max(rowid) from users k where s.name = k.name and s.email = k.email);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * from 
    (SELECT name, email,
        COUNT(name) OVER (PARTITION BY name, email) cnt 
    FROM users)
WHERE cnt > 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT NAME, EMAIL, COUNT(*)
FROM USERS
GROUP BY 1,2
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use having here which work on aggregate functions as shown below

```
create table #TableB (id_account int, data int, [date] date)
insert into #TableB values (1 ,-50, '10/20/2018'),
(1, 20, '10/09/2018'),
(2 ,-900, '10/01/2018'),
(1 ,20, '09/25/2018'),
(1 ,-100, '08/01/2018')  

SELECT id_account , data, COUNT(*)
FROM #TableB
GROUP BY id_account , data
HAVING COUNT(id_account) > 1

drop table #TableB
```

Here as two fields id_account and data are used with Count(*). So, it will give all the records which has more than one times same values in both columns.

We some reason mistakely we had missed to add any constraints in SQL server table and the records has been inserted duplicate in all columns with front-end application. Then we can use below query to delete duplicate query from table.

```
SELECT DISTINCT * INTO #TemNewTable FROM #OriginalTable
TRUNCATE TABLE #OriginalTable
INSERT INTO #OriginalTable SELECT * FROM #TemNewTable
DROP TABLE #TemNewTable
```

Here we have taken all the distinct records of the orignal table and deleted the records of original table. Again we inserted all the distinct values from new table to the original table and then deleted new table.

Answer (score 1):

**Table structure:**

```
ID   NAME   EMAIL
1    John   asd@asd.com
2    Sam    asd@asd.com
3    Tom    asd@asd.com
4    Bob    bob@asd.com
5    Tom    asd@asd.com
```

**Solution 1:**

```
SELECT *,
       COUNT(*)
FROM users t1
INNER JOIN users t2
WHERE t1.id > t2.id
  AND t1.name = t2.name
  AND t1.email=t2.email
```

**Solution 2:**

```
SELECT name,
         email,
       COUNT(*)
FROM users
GROUP BY name,
         email
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The exact code would differ depending on whether you want to find duplicate rows as well or only different ids with the same email and name. If id is a primary key or otherwise has a unique constraint this distinction does not exist, but the question does not specify this. In the former case you can use code given in several other answers:

```
SELECT name, email, COUNT(*)
FROM users
GROUP BY name, email
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

In the latter case you would use:

```
SELECT name, email, COUNT(DISTINCT id)
FROM users
GROUP BY name, email
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT id) > 1
ORDER BY COUNT(DISTINCT id) DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you work with Microsoft Access, this way works:

```sql
CREATE TABLE users (id int, name varchar(10), email varchar(50));

INSERT INTO users VALUES (1, 'John', 'asd@asd.com');
INSERT INTO users VALUES (2, 'Sam', 'asd@asd.com');
INSERT INTO users VALUES (3, 'Tom', 'asd@asd.com');
INSERT INTO users VALUES (4, 'Bob', 'bob@asd.com');
INSERT INTO users VALUES (5, 'Tom', 'asd@asd.com');

SELECT name, email, COUNT(*) AS CountOf
FROM users
GROUP BY name, email
HAVING COUNT(*)>1;

DELETE *
FROM users
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT u1.id 
    FROM users u1, users u2 
    WHERE u1.name = u2.name AND u1.email = u2.email AND u1.id > u2.id
);
```

Thanks to Tancrede Chazallet for the delete code.

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
FROM TABLENAME
    WHERE PrimaryCoumnID NOT IN
    (
        SELECT MAX(PrimaryCoumnID)
        FROM  TABLENAME
        GROUP BY AnyCoumnID
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @myTable TABLE
(
    id INT,
    name VARCHAR(10),
    email VARCHAR(50)
);

INSERT @myTable
VALUES
(1, 'John', 'John-email');
INSERT @myTable
VALUES
(2, 'John', 'John-email');
INSERT @myTable
VALUES
(3, 'fred', 'John-email');
INSERT @myTable
VALUES
(4, 'fred', 'fred-email');
INSERT @myTable
VALUES
(5, 'sam', 'sam-email');
INSERT @myTable
VALUES
(6, 'sam', 'sam-email');

WITH cte
AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS rowNum,
           *
    FROM @myTable)
SELECT c1.id,
       c1.name,
       c1.email
FROM cte AS c1
WHERE 1 <
(
    SELECT COUNT(c2.rowNum)
    FROM cte AS c2
    WHERE c1.name = c2.name
          AND c1.email = c2.email
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `count(*) over (partition by ...)` to select all rows that are duplicate of each other. This approach gives you access to all rows and all columns (unlike `group by` which consolidates duplicates rows and makes ungrouped columns inaccessible).

To *select the original rows* or *delete their duplicates* use `row_number() over (partition by ... order by ...)`.

### Sample data

```
create table t (
  id int not null primary key,
  name varchar(100),
  email varchar(100),
  created date
);

insert into t (id, name, email, created) values
(1, 'Alice', 'alice@example.com', '2021-01-01'),
(2, 'Alice', 'alice@example.com', '2022-01-01'),
(3, 'Alice', 'alice@example.com', '2023-01-01'),
(4, 'Bob',   'bob@example.com',   '2021-01-01'),
(5, 'Bob',   'bob@example.com',   '2022-01-01'),
(6, 'John',  'john@example.com',  '2021-01-01'),
(7, 'Zack',  'zack@example.com',  '2021-01-01');
```

### Select all rows that are duplicate of each other

```
with cte as (
  select t.*, count(*) over (partition by name, email) as dup_count
  from t
)
select *
from cte
where dup_count > 1;
```

##### Result

{ Alice, alice@example.com } is present three times, all three instances are selected
{ John, john@example.com } is present only once, it is excluded

```
| id | name  | email             | created    | dup_count |
|----|-------|-------------------|------------|-----------|
| 1  | Alice | alice@example.com | 2021-01-01 | 3         |
| 2  | Alice | alice@example.com | 2022-01-01 | 3         |
| 3  | Alice | alice@example.com | 2023-01-01 | 3         |
| 4  | Bob   | bob@example.com   | 2021-01-01 | 2         |
| 5  | Bob   | bob@example.com   | 2022-01-01 | 2         |
```

### Select (or delete) the duplicates

The CTE selects all but the oldest row in each set of duplicates
Some RDBMS support delete from CTEs
Or you may use `delete from t where id in (...)` approach

```
with cte as (
  select t.*, row_number() over (partition by name, email order by created) as rn
  from t
)
delete
from cte
where rn > 1;
```

##### Result after deletion

```
| id | name  | email             | created    |
|----|-------|-------------------|------------|
| 1  | Alice | alice@example.com | 2021-01-01 |
| 4  | Bob   | bob@example.com   | 2021-01-01 |
| 6  | John  | john@example.com  | 2021-01-01 |
| 7  | Zack  | zack@example.com  | 2021-01-01 |
```

[DB<>Fiddle - SQL Server](https://dbfiddle.uk/zNZIU52O)
[DB<>Fiddle - MySQL](https://dbfiddle.uk/3CybTnxW)
[DB<>Fiddle - Oracle](https://dbfiddle.uk/pLTM9oAC)

Answer (score -1):

You can use the SELECT DISTINCT keyword to get rid of duplicates. You can also filter by name and get everyone with that name on a table.