# How to return multiple columns when using group by in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I want the names of the employees along with their salary and department who have maximum salary less than 50,000. ihave the following

```
SELECT department, MAX(salary) as Highest salary
FROM employees
GROUP BY department
HAVING MAX(salary) < 50000
```

How do I get the name of the employee to be returned?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So close...

```
SELECT department, name, MAX(salary) as Highest salary
FROM employees
GROUP BY department, name
HAVING MAX(salary) < 50000
```

After comment updates

```
SELECT name, department , salary
FROM employees e
   JOIN
  (
    SELECT department as dept, MAX(salary) as HighestSalary
    FROM employees
    GROUP BY department
  ) MaxE ON e.department = MaxE.dept AND e.salary = MaxE.HighestSalary
```

Comment: You actually understood the question in combination with that query? Congrats!

Comment: @cularis: "I want the names of the employees..". Then I guessed :-)

Comment: @cularis: not everyone understands you can have 2 things to group on, even if bleeding obvious to us Example: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2594829/27535

Comment: what if i want the highest salary from each dept along with the name and department ?

Comment: @gbn I just didn't understand the requirements. For me it sounded like he wants all employees earning less than 50000 along with their department ;)

Comment: what i want now is the name, salary, dept of the employees who earn the maximum in their department ?

Comment: @neverCoded: if you have 3 departments and 100 employees (say split 50-40-10) then you can have either 3 extra rows for the department or add an extra column. And now "maximum in their department": how does this match "< 50000". Think about it, then get back to us

Comment: it was a question asked by my teacher today ! she wanted a query for that. is it possible ? this is my second question. i got the answer for the first one. thanks :)

Comment: Yes, it could be possible. But what?

Comment: the one i asked was my first question. the second question is, to get the name, dept, salary of the employee earning maximum in his dept..

Answer (score 5):

Unless I'm misunderstanding the requirement, just add employee to the select/group by?

```
SELECT employee, department, MAX(salary) as Highest salary
FROM employees
GROUP BY employee, department
HAVING MAX(salary) < 50000
```