# GROUP BY lname ORDER BY showing wrong results

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

This query I've written, listing the top 25 in a sales competition, is showing the wrong results.

Users aren't showing that should be pretty far up on the list. Any idea what the issue could be?

```
SELECT u.fname, u.lname, SUM(p.point) as points 
  FROM comp_sale s, comp_product p, comp_user u
 WHERE s.prod_id = p.product_id 
   AND s.sale_id = u.wp_id 
 GROUP BY lname 
 ORDER BY points DESC limit 25
```

table comp_user:

```
user_id int(11) NO  PRI NULL    auto_increment
fname   varchar(255)    NO      NULL    
lname   varchar(255)    NO      NULL    
storename   varchar(255)    NO      NULL    
city    varchar(255)    NO      NULL    
phone   varchar(255)    NO      NULL    
wp_id   int(11) NO      NULL    
type    varchar(255)    NO      NULL
```

table comp_sale

```
prod_id int(11) NO      NULL    
sale_id int(11) NO      NULL    
serial  varchar(255)    NO      NULL
```

table comp_product

```
product_id  int(11) NO  PRI NULL    auto_increment
description varchar(255)    NO      NULL    
type    varchar(255)    NO      NULL    
cylinda_num int(11) NO      NULL    
eel_num int(11) NO      NULL    
point   int(11) NO      NULL
```

Comment: Why are you grouping by lName? I believe that is the reason for your incorrect results

Comment: isn't query should be like `GROUP BY u.lname ORDER BY p.points`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try using a proper, ANSI standard GROUP BY

```
SELECT
    u.fname, u.lname, SUM(p.point) as points
FROM 
    comp_sale s
    JOIN
    comp_product p ON s.prod_id = p.product_id 
    JOIN
    comp_user u ON s.sale_id = u.wp_id
GROUP BY
    u.fname, u.lname
ORDER BY 
    points DESC 
LIMIT 25
```

Also, use explicit JOINs for clarity

Answer (score 0):

Answer my own question:
I wasn't grouping by `fname` and `lname` but only `lname`.

```
SELECT fname, lname, SUM(point) as points FROM cylinda_sale s, cylinda_product p, cylinda_user u  WHERE s.prod_id = p.product_id AND s.sale_id = u.wp_id GROUP BY lname, fname ORDER BY points DESC limit 25;
```