# C# Asp.net Membership.GetAllUsers order by email

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

I am using Membership.GetAllUsers() to get my user list.  I would like to have the list returned sorted by email address as I need to flag some accounts with duplicate emails.

Membership.GetAllUsers() seems to order by username by default.  Is there a way to change this behavior?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you can live with a generic list rather than a `MembershipUserCollection`:

```
Membership.GetAllUsers().Cast<MembershipUser>().OrderBy(x => x.Email).ToList();
```

Use `OrderBy(x => x.Email, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)` if you want a case-insensitive sort of the email address.

Membership code actually predates generics (it was integrated into .NET 2.0 from a .NET 1.1 development), hence `MembershipUserCollection` does not implement generic interfaces.

Given [your earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11350949/13087), you may be interested in other LINQ-style manipulations.  For example the following will give you a dictionary whose keys are email addresses (case-insensitive), and whose values are lists of corresponding `MembershipUser` objects, sorted by last activity date descending:

```
var dictionary = Membership.GetAllUsers().Cast<MembershipUser>()
    .GroupBy(x => x.Email, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
    .ToDictionary(
                  x => x.Key, 
                  x =>x.OrderByDescending(u => u.LastActivityDate).ToList()
                 );
```

Comment: @peroija, It wasn't his, I edited his post instead of mine by mistake, then corrected it.

Comment: Thanks.   I can live with a generic list for sure.  This looks like it will be a great help but whats the best way to display the data?  I tried your above code with return View(dictionary); but get an error when I try to iterate through the list like so: foreach (var users in dictionary).  Error is: CS0103: The name 'dictionary' does not exist in the current context

Answer (score 2):

The following code should do it, but it may not have the best performance.

```
Membership.GetAllUsers().Cast<MembershipUser>().OrderBy(m => m.Email);
```

It does the sorting in memory, rather than as a db query.

Answer (score 1):

```
Membership.GetAllUsers().OrderBy(user => user.Email).ToList();
```

Comment: This code won't actually compile, because `MembershipUserCollection` implements `IEnumerable`, and not `IEnumerable<T>`.  So LINQ extension methods won't work with the MembershipUserCollection.  You first need to perform a cast operation on each element and convert it to an `IEnumerable` like this: `Membership.GetAllUsers().Cast<MembershipUser>()`

Comment: No problem! I just noticed my typo - when I said "convert it to an `IEnumerable`", I meant "convert it to an `IEnumerable<T>`".