# Select rows with the same field values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

How can I query only the records that show up twice in my table?

Currently my table looks something like this:

```
Number   Date                  RecordT     ReadLoc
123      08/13/13 1:00pm       N           Gone
123      08/13/13 2:00pm       P           Home
123      08/13/13 3:00pm       N           Away
123      08/13/13 4:00pm       N           Away
```

I need a query that will select the records that have the same 'Value' in the RecordT field and the same 'Value' in the ReadLoc field.

So my result for the above would show with the query:

```
Number   Date                  RecordT     ReadLoc
123      08/13/13 3:00pm       N           Away
123      08/13/13 4:00pm       N           Away
```

I was trying to do a subselect like this:

```sql
SELECT t.Number, t.Date, n.RecordT, n.ReadLoc
FROM Table1 t join Table2 n ON t.Number = n.Number
WHERE t.Number IN (SELECT t.Number FROM Table1 GROUP BY t.Number HAVING COUNT(t.Number) > 1 )
AND n.ReadLoc IN (SELECT n.ReadLoc FROM Table2 GROUP n.ReadLoc HAVING COUNT(n.ReadLoc) > 1 )
```

Comment: Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2594829/finding-duplicate-values-in-a-sql-table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT a.*
FROM Table1 a
JOIN (SELECT RecordT, ReadLoc
      FROM Table1
      GROUP BY RecordT, ReadLoc
      HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
      )b
ON a.RecordT = b.RecordT
 AND a.ReadLoc = b.ReadLoc
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ecff8/1/0)

Comment: Sure thing, as ultimately the inner join shown above will limit all results to multiples.

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't this work:

```
select * 
from table1 
where (RecordT, ReadLoc) in 
   (select RecordT, ReadLoc 
    from table1 
    group by RecordT, ReadLoc 
    having count(*) > 1)
```

Comment: Probably want `> 1` not `= 2`

Comment: For some reason it doesn't like the ',' I get Incorrect syntax near ','.

Comment: I didn't realize you are using sql server. This is oracle syntax. The answer mentioned by "Goat CO" should work for sql server.

Answer (score 1):

The following can be taken as a base:

```
;with cte as (
    select *, cnt = count(1) over (partition by RecordT, ReadLoc)
    from TableName
)
select *
from cte
where cnt > 1
```

If your `TableName` is actually a view of two joined tables, try:

```
;with TableName as (
    SELECT t.Number, t.Date, n.RecordT, n.ReadLoc
    FROM Table1 t
        join Table2 n ON t.Number = n.Number
),
cte as (
    select Number, Date, RecordT, ReadLoc,
        cnt = count(1) over (partition by RecordT, ReadLoc)
    from TableName
)
select Number, Date, RecordT, ReadLoc
from cte
where cnt > 1 /* and RecordT='N' and ReadLoc='AWAY' */
```

Comment: I was trying this method but I don't get the correct results. I have multiple JOINs in the query. `WITH    MoreThanTwo
          AS ( SELECT t.Number, t.Date, n.RecordT, n.ReadLoc, cnt = COUNT(1) OVER (partition by RecordT, ReadLoc)
FROM Table1 t join Table2 n ON t.Number = n.Number
WHERE n.RecordT = 'N' AND n.ReadLoc = 'AWAY' )   SELECT  *
    FROM    MoreThanTwo
    WHERE   cnt > 1`