# SQL to list only the duplicates on certain col

Tags: sql

Select * from PBM.T_CHARGES where TIER <> 'T1' and STAT NOT IN (3,4,5)

I want to list only where the RX number is repeated in the table.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finding duplicate values in a SQL table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2594829/finding-duplicate-values-in-a-sql-table)

Answer (score 2):

Use a GROUP BY with the HAVING

```
Select RX from PBM.T_CHARGES where TIER <> 'T1' and STAT NOT IN (3,4,5)
GROUP BY RX
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```