# finding duplication in data

Tags: sql, duplicates

I have data of students' result. Each student has appeared in 5 subjects. Few students have more than 5 records in database. Student having 2 records in "Science" and 1 for each remaining subjects. total 6 records. example is given here.

**sample data:**

```
RollNo          Subject   TOTAL_MARKS
-------------------------------------
11-119-302        ENGL      34
11-119-302        MATH      56
11-119-302        SCIE      44
11-119-302        SCIE      24
11-119-302        URDU      76
```

I want to get all the fields of those students having duplicate subjects.

**Required output:**

```
RollNo          Subject   TOTAL_MARKS
-------------------------------------    
11-119-302        ENGL      34
11-119-302        ENGL      56
11-119-333        SCIE      44
11-119-333        SCIE      24
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finding duplicate values in a SQL table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2594829/finding-duplicate-values-in-a-sql-table)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this

```
DECLARE @MARKS TABLE (ROLLNO VARCHAR(20),SUBJECT VARCHAR(20), TOTAL_MARKS INT)
INSERT INTO @MARKS VALUES 
('11-119-302','ENGL',34),
('11-119-302','MATH',56),
('11-119-302','SCIE',44),
('11-119-302','SCIE',24),
('11-119-302','URDU',76)

SELECT  *
FROM    @MARKS M JOIN (
SELECT  ROLLNO,SUBJECT,COUNT(*) C FROM @MARKS GROUP BY ROLLNO,SUBJECT HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) LU
ON      M.ROLLNO = LU.ROLLNO AND M.SUBJECT = LU.SUBJECT
```

--Result

[image]

Comment: Jithin thanks a lot. your query worked exactly. but it is a little bit complicated to understand. Is it possible to have any alternate query? or a query without Join?

Comment: Youness ur query selects all the records from table, whereas query suggested by Jithin produce correct output. can you simplify Jithin query?

Comment: @ShahNawaz, are u asking, whether the SQL can be even simplified.?

Comment: yes Jithin, is there any simplied sql query instead what you addred previously.

Comment: I am not sure, May be someone will come up with a better answer.
But the one specified is a simple one. It only does basic operations.

Comment: Jithin Consider this, is it an alternate of your query?

Comment: SELECT rollno,  Subject, COUNT(*) FROM RRAttock
GROUP BY RollNo, Subject
HAVING  COUNT(*) > 1
 order by RollNo

Comment: Only difference is, this query do not returns all fields of table

Comment: You query will give like (rollno --> 11-119-302 Subject --> SCIE (No column name) --> 2). You wont get the result you asked in the question.Again it should be COUNT(*), not COUNT()

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
select * from results where
         num in ( select num from results group by num having count(num)>2)
```