# Finding a keyword in duplicate values in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I am trying to find the keyword "img" in the duplicate values in my SQL database using the answer in this post:
[Finding duplicate values in a SQL table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2594829/finding-duplicate-values-in-a-sql-table). I want to select those duplicate values in my database that have a "img" keyword in either of 'question', 'option' or 'solution' column.

My SQL statement looks like this:

```
SELECT
    `subject`, `topic`, `sub_topic`, `difficulty`,`question_number`,`question_version`, COUNT(*)
FROM
    `qz_question`
GROUP BY
    `topic`, `sub_topic`, `difficulty`,`question_number`,`question_version`
WHERE 
    `option` LIKE  '%img%' OR `question` LIKE  '%img%' OR `solution` LIKE  '%img%'
```

This returns me this error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE `option` LIKE '%img%' OR `question` LIKE '%img%' OR `solution` ' at line 7
```

How do I correct this error? Need some guidance on this.

Comment: `WHERE` comes before `GROUP BY`

Comment: this produces a long list of data then when I find just duplicate values without any where clauses. this produces all the rows that have "img" in them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your sql has some syntax error. I modified that error execute and see

```
SELECT
        `subject`, `topic`, `sub_topic`, `difficulty`,`question_number`,`question_version`, COUNT(*)
    FROM
        `qz_question`
    WHERE 
        `option` LIKE  '%img%' OR `question` LIKE  '%img%' OR `solution` LIKE  '%img%'
    GROUP BY
        `topic`, `sub_topic`, `difficulty`,`question_number`,`question_version`
```

These bottom SQL shows only duplicate records.

```
SELECT `subject`, `topic`, `sub_topic`, `difficulty`,`question_number`,`question_version`, COUNT(*) as c
    FROM
        `qz_question`
    WHERE 
        `option` LIKE  '%img%' OR `question` LIKE  '%img%' OR `solution` LIKE  '%img%'
    GROUP BY
        `topic`, `sub_topic`, `difficulty`,`question_number`,`question_version`
        HAVING c > 1;
```

Thank you.

Comment: why WHERE needs to come before GROUP BY?

Comment: meaning after filter the record and then group by the records. its actual SQL syntax.