# How to display all the columns of the duplicate values in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I would like to display all the columns of the duplicate values in MYSQL.

I am selecting the duplicate values in MYSQL based on this post:[Finding duplicate values in a SQL table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2594829/finding-duplicate-values-in-a-sql-table).

MY sql statement looks like this:

```
    SELECT
        `subject`, `topic`, `sub_topic`, `difficulty`,`question_number`,`question_version`, COUNT(*)
    FROM
        `qz_question`
    GROUP BY
        `topic`, `sub_topic`, `difficulty`,`question_number`,`question_version`
    HAVING 
        COUNT(*) > 1
```

Instead of Grouping by the columns, I would like to display all the columns of all the duplicate values in the database.

I have tried this:

```
SELECT
        *
    FROM
        `qz_question`
    GROUP BY
        `topic`, `sub_topic`, `difficulty`,`question_number`,`question_version`
    HAVING 
        COUNT(*) > 1
```

For example, for each unique row, there is a duplicate. It should display both the unique and the duplicate together at the same time.But this displays only one unique row. I want the duplicate as well.

Comment: Can you share your db structure?

Comment: Can you try with "DISTINCT" function

Comment: You want to find duplicate values of what fields?

Comment: `subject`, `topic`, `sub_topic`, `difficulty`,`question_number`,`question_version`

Comment: Can you show what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to display all the duplicate values in my database. Edited my question

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to do something like this:

```
SELECT  q1.*, q2.dups
FROM    qz_question q1
        JOIN ( SELECT   subject ,
                        topic ,
                        sub_topic ,
                        difficulty ,
                        question_number ,
                        question_version ,
                        COUNT(*) AS dups
               FROM     qz_question
               GROUP BY topic ,
                        sub_topic ,
                        difficulty ,
                        question_number ,
                        question_version
               HAVING   COUNT(*) > 1
             ) q2 ON q1.topic = q2.topic
                     AND q1.sub_topic = q2.sub_topic
                     AND q1.difficulty = q2.difficulty
                     AND q1.question_number = q2.question_number
                     AND q1.question_version = q2.question_version
```

Comment: At times, it shows the rows that are not duplicates and I need to have delete functionality at the side. How do i do it?

Comment: At what times? May be you should add ordering at the end to see duplicates? One row may be at top of result and the duplicate may appear somewhere in the end.

Comment: But how to have the delete functionality at the side, I am using phpmyadmin for each row.

Comment: Original question didn't mentioned that you wanted to delete. What you want to leave and what you want to delete?

Comment: I don't want to delete using query but manually. So I need a delete button at each row. How do I do it?

Comment: @lakesh, I have no idea what you are talking about. This question is fully answered. Ask another question. I know nothing about php and phpadmin.