# Check uniqness of data with Sequel

Tags: sql, ruby, postgresql, sequel

I use the PostgreSQL database with Sequel. I have the following data in my table: `table.all` returns following data:

```
  [{:id=>1,
  :identifier=>"identifier",
  :first_name=>"First",
  :middle_name=>"M.",
  :last_name=>"Last 2",
  :email=>"some@email.com"},
 {:id=>2,
  :identifier=>"identifier",
  :first_name=>"First 2",
  :middle_name=>"A.",
  :last_name=>"Last2 ",
  :email=>"some@email2.com"}]
```

Now I want to find ids of record which identifier belongs to more than one first_name - last_name combination. So in this example we have two records with the same identifier but different first and last names. Is there any way to do this in Sequel?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding duplicate values in a SQL table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2594829/finding-duplicate-values-in-a-sql-table)

Comment: My example is bit more advanced than in that topic that You linked and I have to use Sequel.