# Display only unique values from a column of a 2d array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, duplicates

How can I remove the duplicate values in the `foreach` statement?

Here is my `$data` array:

```
$data = [
    [
        'idx' => 1,
        'id' => 1,
        'mname' => 'test1',
        'hname' => 'test1',
        'bdate' => '0000-00-00',
    ],
    [
        'idx' => 2,
        'id' => 1,
        'mname' => 'test1',
        'hname' => 'test1',
        'bdate' => '0000-00-00',
    ],
    [
        'idx' => 3,
        'id' => 1,
        'mname' => 'test1',
        'hname' => 'test1',
        'bdate' => '0000-00-00',
    ],
    [
        'idx' => 4,
        'id' => 1,
        'mname' => 'test1',
        'hname' => 'test1',
        'bdate' => '2024-01-01',
    ],
    [
        'idx' => 5,
        'id' => 1,
        'mname' => 'test1',
        'hname' => 'test1',
        'bdate' => '2024-01-03',
    ],
    [
        'idx' => 6,
        'id' => 1,
        'mname' => 'test1',
        'hname' => 'test1',
        'bdate' => '2024-01-05',
    ],
    [
        'idx' => 7,
        'id' => 1,
        'mname' => 'test1',
        'hname' => 'test1',
        'bdate' => '2024-01-07',
    ],
    [
        'idx' => 8,
        'id' => 1,
        'mname' => 'test1',
        'hname' => 'test1',
        'bdate' => '2024-01-09',
    ],
    [
        'idx' => 9,
        'id' => 1,
        'mname' => 'test1',
        'hname' => 'test1',
        'bdate' => '0000-00-00',
    ],
    [
        'idx' => 10,
        'id' => 1,
        'mname' => 'test1',
        'hname' => 'test1',
        'bdate' => '2024-01-20',
    ],
    [
        'idx' => 11,
        'id' => 1,
        'mname' => 'test1',
        'hname' => 'test1',
        'bdate' => '0000-00-00',
    ],
    [
        'idx' => 12,
        'id' => 1,
        'mname' => 'test1',
        'hname' => 'test1',
        'bdate' => '0000-00-00',
    ],
    [
        'idx' => 13,
        'id' => 1,
        'mname' => 'test1',
        'hname' => 'test1',
        'bdate' => '0000-00-00',
    ],
    [
        'idx' => 14,
        'id' => 1,
        'mname' => 'test1',
        'hname' => 'test1',
        'bdate' => '2024-01-22',
    ],
    [
        'idx' => 15,
        'id' => 1,
        'mname' => 'test1',
        'hname' => 'test1',
        'bdate' => '2024-01-22',
    ],
    [
        'idx' => 16,
        'id' => 1,
        'mname' => 'test1',
        'hname' => 'test1',
        'bdate' => '2024-01-22',
    ],
    [
        'idx' => 17,
        'id' => 1,
        'mname' => 'test1',
        'hname' => 'test1',
        'bdate' => '2024-01-22',
    ],
    [
        'idx' => 18,
        'id' => 1,
        'mname' => 'test1',
        'hname' => 'test1',
        'bdate' => '2024-01-22',
    ],
    [
        'idx' => 19,
        'id' => 1,
        'mname' => 'test1',
        'hname' => 'test1',
        'bdate' => '2024-01-22',
    ],
    [
        'idx' => 20,
        'id' => 1,
        'mname' => 'test1',
        'hname' => 'test1',
        'bdate' => '2024-01-22',
    ],
    [
        'idx' => 21,
        'id' => 1,
        'mname' => 'test1',
        'hname' => 'test1',
        'bdate' => '2024-01-22',
    ],
    [
        'idx' => 22,
        'id' => 1,
        'mname' => 'test1',
        'hname' => 'test1',
        'bdate' => '2024-01-22',
    ],
    [
        'idx' => 23,
        'id' => 1,
        'mname' => 'test1',
        'hname' => 'test1',
        'bdate' => '2024-01-22',
    ],
    [
        'idx' => 24,
        'id' => 1,
        'mname' => 'test1',
        'hname' => 'test1',
        'bdate' => '2024-01-22',
    ],
    [
        'idx' => 25,
        'id' => 1,
        'mname' => 'test1',
        'hname' => 'test1',
        'bdate' => '2024-01-22',
    ],
    [
        'idx' => 26,
        'id' => 1,
        'mname' => 'test1',
        'hname' => 'test1',
        'bdate' => '2024-01-22',
    ],
    [
        'idx' => 27,
        'id' => 1,
        'mname' => 'test1',
        'hname' => 'test1',
        'bdate' => '2024-01-22',
    ],
    [
        'idx' => 28,
        'id' => 1,
        'mname' => 'test1',
        'hname' => 'test1',
        'bdate' => '2024-01-22',
    ],
```

**Code**

```
<?php
    foreach ($data as $row){
        if($row['bdate'] == '0000-00-00'){
            continue;
        }
        echo '<li>'.$row['bdate'].'</li>';
    }
?>
```

It displays like the following.

```
2024-01-01
2024-01-03
2024-01-05
2024-01-07
2024-01-09
2024-01-20
2024-01-22
2024-01-22
2024-01-22
2024-01-22
2024-01-22
2024-01-22
2024-01-22
2024-01-22
2024-01-22
2024-01-22
2024-01-22
2024-01-22
2024-01-22
2024-01-22
2024-01-22
2024-01-22
2024-01-22
```

But what I want to display like this:

```
2024-01-01
2024-01-03
2024-01-05
2024-01-07
2024-01-09
2024-01-20
2024-01-22
```

How can I remove duplicated same date value ?

Comment: Again - if you are using SQL to fetch the unique dates - look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34312757/mysql-select-unique-value. You can also combine this with the ORDER BY and solve all your problems without all this extra code.

Comment: @Gin [`$unique = array_column($array, 'bdate', 'bdate');
unset($unique['0000-00-00']);
var_export(array_values($unique));`](https://3v4l.org/JsMkd)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using an associative array. You can keep track of the dates that have already been printed.

```
$printed_dates = array();
foreach ($data as $row){
    if($row['bdate'] == '0000-00-00' || isset($printed_dates[$row['bdate']])){
        continue;
    }
    $printed_dates[$row['bdate']] = true;
    echo '<li>'.$row['bdate'].'</li>';
}
```

Comment: There are much simpler and quicker ways of doing this.

Comment: @Karl Please search for duplicate pages instead of racing to post an answer to basic questions asked in 2024.