# sql select duplicates and singles

Tags: mysql, sql

so i have a database table like:

```
NAME  name_ID
---------------
Joao    1
Maria   3
Joao    1 
carlos  2 
carlos  2
```

i want to do a select query that displays all duplicates only like this :

```
NAME  name_ID
---------------
Joao    1
Joao    1 
carlos  2 
carlos  2
```

and other select query that displays singles like so :

```
 NAME  name_ID
  ---------------
    Maria 3
```

Comment: I guess you didn't google "sql duplicates"? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2594829/finding-duplicate-values-in-a-sql-table

Answer (score 1):

This would be simpler if you had a unique id column in each table.  I encourage you to design tables with primary keys.

In any case, you can do this with a query of the form for duplicates:

```
select t.*
from databasetable t join
     (select name, count(*) as cnt
      from databasetable
      group by name
     ) tt
     on t.name = tt.name
where cnt > 1;
```

For singletons, the comparison would be `cnt = 1`.

EDIT:

With a unique id and an index on `(name, id)`, the following is probably faster for duplicates:

```
select t.*
from databasetabe t
where exists (select 1
              from databasetable t2
              where t2.name = t.name and t2.id <> t.id
             );
```

Singletons would use `not exists` instead.

Answer (score 0):

select name from table group by name haveing count(*)=1  ###for Maria

select * from table where not in (previous select) order by name