# How to get duplicate records with the combination of two rows in django?

Tags: django

I am using unique_together constraint in my model.

```
class Facility(models.Model):
    institute = models.ForeignKey(Institute)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('institute', 'name',)
```

How can I get the duplicate values with same name and institute?

Comment: You can't, the constraint makes sure, that anytime you will try to insert (update) a duplicate value with the `'institute'` and `'name'`, that already exist in the table, an exception will be raised.

Answer (score 0):

After set meta unique_together

> **it's mean when you try to save duplicate value in DB Django not allow this and throw an exception** 
>   ,means there is no duplicate value in DB.

According to your model structure if you don't want to save duplicate entries in DB then delete all previous entries first then run make migrations and migrate.

Comment: Actually I have some data in database. Later I want to add that unique_together so before that i want to check once

Comment: SELECT
    y.id,y.name,y.email
    FROM YourTable y
        INNER JOIN (SELECT
                        name,email, COUNT(*) AS CountOf
                        FROM  YourTable
                        GROUP BY name,email
                        HAVING COUNT(*)>1
                    ) dt ON y.name=dt.name and y.email=dt.email

Comment: Use this query for get duplicate data from table.
Note: Change all veriable names accordingly like:  GROUP BY  institute,name

Comment: follow this for more operations : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2594829/finding-duplicate-values-in-a-sql-table