# Need to find duplicates where two columns values added together create a duplicate

Tags: sql, duplicates, display

Problem:  There is a conference.  Each class in the conference will run three times (time1, time2, time3).  Attendee can only go to one session per class.  I'm looking for duplicate class registrations.  (User is going to class1: time1 and time2)

I need to write a query to find duplicate registrations with information in 3 different tables.  The tables I'm joining are (class, user, registration).  I need to find all duplicates that are created by adding the values for two columns.  (class.title + user.id#) = duplicate.

I need the query to display only the duplicate rows found plus display additional column information such as id number, title, first, last, status.

### For Example:  The search would find these results

[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nsTcR.png)

But display only...
[results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6AWW.png)

I'm not sure where to start.  The information in class.title + user.id# will vary per row, so I can't search by specific information.  (ie:  user.id#=45624).

Comment: It would be useful if you clarify the programming language you are using and the code that you have.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding duplicate values in a SQL table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2594829/finding-duplicate-values-in-a-sql-table)

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you right is the `DISTINCT`-Keyword what you are looking for: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp

An example:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT DISTINCT title, status, first, last FROM your_table)
```

This will make sure that there will be no duplicate rows returned identified by `title`, `status`, `first` and `last`.

---

I may misunderstood your question. In case you are looking for duplicates **only**, consider the following code. This will return you all duplicate rows identified by `title`, `status`, `first` and `last` and give you `id` as an additional information.

```
SELECT id, title, status, first, last
    FROM your_table
GROUP BY title, status, first, last
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

---

Which one is the answer you were looking for?

Comment: I want to only show the duplicate rows.  I don't want to display distinct rows. 

The duplicate is not the same value located in two columns.  I want to display duplicates that are created by adding the information in two columns together to determine the duplicate. 

for example:   

title1 + user#1 = duplicate  (display)

title2+user#1 = distinct (don't display)

Comment: Sorry I don't really understand your example. Are two rows with the same `title` and `user#` duplicates in your opinion?

Comment: Yes.  If row 1 and row 2 have the same title and user#, it is a duplicate.

Comment: Alright, this is exactly what my second solution will return to you.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this will work

```
    select * from(
    SELECT id, title, status, first, last ,
row_number() over ( partition by id, title order by status) rowid 
        FROM your_table
        ) x
        where rowid = 2
```