# Finding Similar data from tables

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, database

I have a very huge data but some of data has been duplicated such as for Example First Row has name "Sushil" and other row has name "Sushil and Other" the relevant details of both rows are same.
So how can i find such a data.
Please Help..!

Comment: which DBMS are you using? mySQL or SQL server? Don't tag products you aren't using!!

Comment: I am Using Mysql DBMS

Comment: then you should untag SQL server

Comment: How pls tell me the procedure..

Comment: I still not get the Answer...Brother

Answer (score 1):

You have to write the aggregate functions to find the counts of duplicated fields
(By using Group By Clause).

refer the below answer

[StackOverflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2594829/finding-duplicate-values-in-a-sql-table)

Comment: But how..Can u pls explain brief

Comment: hallo brother..can we find the data like within same ROW the data is enter like  FIRST row has "JOHN" name   and somewhere else in same ROW it is enter as "JOHN And Others"..So i want to find both the data fro tables..

Comment: I still not get the Answer...Brother

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have this table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table_1](
    [name] [nchar](10) NULL,
    [age] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

you can execute the following query on this table

```
SELECT t.*, COUNT(*) as DuplicateRecords
FROM Table_1 t
group by t.name,t.age having COUNT(*)>=2
```

the result set would contain rows that are duplicated.

Comment: I still not get the Answer...Brother

Comment: can you please elaborate as to why you are still having problems ?

Comment: Brother..your query is executing properly..but not in way that i want

Comment: My problem is that I want to show all data that is entered as in For Ex. in a First_name column First_name is "SUSHIL" and somewhere in another row within same column i.e. in First_name data is enterd as "SUSHIL and  Other" and other details like mob. No and etc of both "SUSHIL" and "SUSHIL and Other" is same i.e. Repeated

Comment: `select * from table where firstname like '%and Other%'` Execute this query