# Uisng exists in sql to find duplicates, is there a cleaner way?

Tags: sql-server, exists

See script below to find duplicates in SQL Server DB. Is there a cleaner way?

```
select itemnum 
from matusetrans a
where exists (select null 
              from matusetrans b 
              where a.itemnum = b.itemnum 
                and a.actualdate = b.actualdate 
                and a.matusetransid != b.matusetransid 
                and (a.rotassetnum = b.rotassetnum 
                     or (a.rotassetnum is null and b.rotassetnum is null))    
                and a.quantity = b.quantity)
group by itemnum
```

Comment: Please define "duplicates" clearly. Are you referring to two records where all the columns in the row match?

Comment: Hi Mfusiki, yes duplicates where the criteria within the code match and the count is > 1.

Comment: Please refer to this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2594829/finding-duplicate-values-in-a-sql-table

Comment: With this thread I am unable to identify the unique itemnum.

Comment: as @Mfusiki suggested, use GroupBy & Having Clause

Comment: But then I am unable to select the unique itemnum

Comment: If you are checking for duplicate rows the item number will never truly be unique?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another possibility (but not neccessarily "cleaner") might be

```
WITH cte AS(
  SELECT columns, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY columns ORDER by columns) AS RowIdx
    FROM matusetrans
    GROUP BY columns
)
SELECT *
  FROM cte
  WHERE RowIdx > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
SELECT itemnum
FROM matusetrans
GROUP BY [ColumnNames]
HAVING 
COUNT(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to find duplicate itemnum in table,Please use below query

```
SELECT itemnum
FROM matusetrans
GROUP BY [ItemNum]
HAVING COUNT(ItemNum) > 1
```

Using `HAVING COUNT(*) > 1` may give you result as all are distinct if there are any `Datetime` columns like order datetime which generally varies per record.

Thanks,
Sree