# How to Check Duplicate value SQL table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am  using SQL server.Import data from  Excel . i have Following  Fields column

```
 Entity ExpenseTypeCode Amount  Description APSupplierID    ExpenseReportID 
   12     001            5       Dinner      7171                  90
   12     001            6       Dinner      7171                  90
   12     001            5       Dinner      7273                  90
   12     001            5       Dinner      7171                  95
   12     001            5       Dinner      7171                  90
```

I added Sample Data. Now I want select Duplicate Records .which Rows have all columns value same  i want fetch that row. suppose above My table Fifth Row duplicate . i have more four thousands Query . i want  select Duplicate records .Above I mention .  please How to select using Query ?

Comment: refer to this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2594829/finding-duplicate-values-in-a-sql-table

Answer (score 1):

If you want the values that are duplicated, then use `group by`:

```
select Entity, ExpenseTypeCode, Amount, Description, APSupplierID,     ExpenseReportID, count(*) as numDuplicates
from t
group by Entity, ExpenseTypeCode, Amount, Description, APSupplierID,     ExpenseReportID 
having count(*) > 1;
```