# Is there any optimised way in sql sever to optimse this code, I am trying to find 2nd duplicate

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Is there any optimised way in sql sever to optimse this code, I am trying to find 2nd duplicate

```
 WITH CTE AS    (
                     SELECT *,
                     ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id,AN_KEY ORDER BY [ENTITYID]) AS [rn]
                     FROM [data].[dbo].[TRANSFER]
                      ) 
                        select *
                        INTO dbo.#UpSingle 
                        from CTE 
                        where RN=2
```

Comment: Does this query do what you want?

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:**

As GurV pointed out - this query doesn't solve the problem. It will only give you the items that have exactly two duplicates, but not the row where the second duplicate lies.

I am just going to leave this here from reference purposes.

**Original Answer**

Why not try something like this from another SO post: [Finding duplicate values in a SQL table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2594829/finding-duplicate-values-in-a-sql-table)

```
SELECT
    id, AN_KEY, COUNT(*)
FROM
    [data].[dbo].[TRANSFER]
GROUP BY
    id, AN_KEY
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) = 2
```

I gather from your original SQL that the cols you would want to group by on are :

- Id
- AN_KEY

Comment: Wrong. How is this finding the second duplicate row?

Comment: You're right, sorry, this doesn't get the duplicate row - it only returns the items that have exactly two occurrences

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to get the the second duplicate row (in the order of increasing ENTITYID of course):

```
select *
from [data].[dbo].[TRANSFER] a
where [ENTITYID] = (
        select min([ENTITYID])
        from [data].[dbo].[TRANSFER] b
        where [ENTITYID] > (
                select min([ENTITYID])
                from [data].[dbo].[TRANSFER] c
                where b.id = c.id
                    and b.an_key = c.an_key
                )
            and a.id = b.id
            and a.an_key = b.an_key
        )
```

Provided there is an index on id, an_key and ENTITYID columns, performance of both your query and this should be acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

Let me assume that this query does what you want:

```
WITH CTE AS  (
      SELECT t.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id, AN_KEY
                                ORDER BY [ENTITYID]) AS [rn]
      FROM [data].[dbo].[TRANSFER] t
     ) 
SELECT *
INTO dbo.#UpSingle 
FROM CTE 
WHERE RN = 2;
```

For performance, you want a composite index on `[data].[dbo].[TRANSFER](id, AN_KEY, ENTITYID)`.