# Finding orders that have been ordered multiple times (SQL query)

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to find out which orders have been made more than once. This will help me identify the most common orders. Here is my orders table with some dummy data;

Table name: Orders

`OrderID | ProductID | Quantity 
-------- | ----------| --------
1        | 3         | 6       |
1        | 6         | 3       |
2        | 5         | 1       |
3        | 10        | 9       |
3        | 9         | 1       |
3        | 3         | 2       |
4        | 6         | 3       |
4        | 3         | 6       |`

As you can see orders 1 and 4 are the same order I need a query to help me identify these orders.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding duplicate values in a SQL table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2594829/finding-duplicate-values-in-a-sql-table)

Comment: Why can two orders have the same ID? That seems confusing to me from a table design standpoint. How is uniqueness of orders determined ?

Comment: `As you can see orders 1 and 4 are the same order` ... this isn't clear to me at all.  What makes them the same order?

Comment: They have the same productID and same quantity @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: @TheOperant If that determines uniqueness, then how could the second OrderID = 1 row exist.

Comment: I think your question should've been `Finding Products that have been ordered multiple times`.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen -- an order can have any number of rows -- I'm guessing only 1 per product

Comment: Ah ok I see, it is a single item in that order. That makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a group by and having like this

```
SELECT OrderID, ProductID, Quantity, Count(*) as Count
FROM Your_table_name_which_you_did_not_tell_us
GROUP BY OrderID, ProductID, Quantity
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: He left a comma out between ProductID and Quantity @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: @TheOperant -- my name is Hogan but thank you for catching the typo.

Answer (score 0):

FYI this did the job for me;

`"SELECT MIN(orderID) as orderId, COUNT(*) as TimesOrdered"
        + " FROM ORDERS"
        + " GROUP BY partId, quantity"
        + " HAVING COUNT(*)>1";`