# SQL - need to return products that are NOT in one table

Tags: sql

My query needs to return the products that are not sourced. All products are listed in the inventory table, but only the ones that have a vendor associated with them are in the vendor_item table. I have tried the following statement just to get back "no data found"

```
SELECT i.item_name "Products Not Sourced", vi.item_num "Item Number"
FROM inventory i RIGHT OUTER JOIN vendor_item vi ON i.item_num=vi.item_num
WHERE vi.item_num IS NULL
```

Logical model this is all based on:-

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G3lXF.png)]

Comment: Please do not use tags that do not apply to your question. I removed the database tags as it is unclear which one you are actually using. Please add the tag of *only* the database you are actually using

Comment: What is the point of selecting `vi.item_num` - it will be `NULL` in all rows, right?  Then: You can do this with an outer join like you did (with the modification proposed in SqlZim's answer), but it would be simpler to `select item_name from mnathan3_SID_inventory where item_num not in (select item_num from mnathan3_SID_vendor_item)` (assuming the item number can't be `null` in either table).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding duplicate values in a SQL table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2594829/finding-duplicate-values-in-a-sql-table)

Answer (score 3):

Try a `left join` instead of a `right join` with that order of tables.

```
select 
   i.item_name "Products Not Sourced"
 , vi.item_num "Item Number"
from mnathan3_SID_inventory i
  left join mnathan3_SID_vendor_item vi 
    on i.item_num = vi.item_num
where vi.item_num is null
```

Otherwise reverse the order of the tables:

```
select 
   i.item_name "Products Not Sourced"
 , vi.item_num "Item Number"
from mnathan3_SID_vendor_item vi
  right join mnathan3_SID_inventory i
    on i.item_num = vi.item_num
where vi.item_num is null
```

Answer (score -1):

Hope you should use the normal joins.

Left and Right Outer Joins exclude some of the content in the table.

Comment: Not really an answer, at least a complete one.