# Select unique subsets

Tags: sql

I have a table like in example below.

SQL> select * from test;

```
    ID  PARENT_ID NAME
     1          1 A
     2          1 B
     3          2 A
     4          2 B
     5          3 A
     6          3 B
     7          3 C
     8          4 A
```

What I need is to get all unique subsets of names ((A,B), (A,B,C), (A)) or exclude duplicate subsets. You can see that (A,B) is twice there, one for PARENT_ID=1 and one for 2. 
I want to exclude such duplicates:

```
ID  PARENT_ID NAME
1          1 A
2          1 B  
5          3 A
6          3 B
7          3 C
8          4 A
```

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Tag only with the database you are using.

Comment: The one you posted below, is that the desired result? (Just clarifying)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding duplicate values in a SQL table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2594829/finding-duplicate-values-in-a-sql-table)

Comment: In the end I don't need ID. I need to have PARENT_IDs and NAMes because I need them for another SQL statements.

Answer (score 0):

I have used 'group_concat' assuming you are using 'Mysql'. The equivalent function in Oracle is 'listagg()'. you can see it in action [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3f4d4/1/0) in SQL fiddle

Here is the solution:-

```
Select a.* from
test a
inner join
(
Select nm, min(parent_id) as p_id
from
    (
    Select Parent_id, group_concat(NAME) as nm
    from test
    group by  Parent_ID
    ) a
group by nm
)b
on a.Parent_id=b.p_id 
order by parent_id, name
```

Comment: I also found that 'group_concat' equivalent on Oracle will help but I thought it's a bad idea (performance reasons; haven't thested it though).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DISTINCT` to only return different values.

e.g.

```
SELECT DISTINCT GROUP_CONCAT(NAME SEPARATOR ',') as subsets 
FROM TABLE_1
GROUP BY PARENT_ID;
```

[image]

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/199e08/1)

Comment: Except based on the output, the question asks for the Parent_ID and names to be kept separate.  and based on output keep the minimum parent_ID only if duplicates exist.

Comment: @xQbert yeah that's what I'm really wondering if how he wanted to see the results. If `((A,B), (A,B,C), (A))` or the one he posted at the bottom. But still I haven't got his confirmation yet. So I decide to give an answer as he might want this format.