# MAX of SUM and use of TOP in Views

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following tables in SQL Server:

- `COMMANDLINES`: ID_LINE - ID_COMMAND - ID_ARTICLE - QUANTITY
- `COMMAND`: ID_COMMAND - ID_CLIENT - PRICE - PRINTED
- `CLIENT`: ID_CLIENT - FULL_NAME - SSN - PH_NUM - MOBILE - USERNAME - PASSWORD
- `ARTICLE`: ID_ARTICLE - DES - NAME - PRICE - TYPE - CURRENT_QTT - MINIMUM_QTT
- `ID_COMMAND` from `COMMANDLINES` references `COMMAND.ID_COMMAND`
- `ID_CLIENT` from `COMMAND` references `CLIENT.ID_CLIENT`
- `ID_ARTICLE` from `COMMANDLINES` references `ARTICLE.ID_ARTICLE`

I need to create a `view` where I need to show all `COMMANDLINES` that have the best client (the one with the highest total of `PRICE`) and then I need to order them by `ID_COMMAND` in a descending order AND by `ID_LINE` in ascending order.

**Sample data:**

`COMMANDLINE` table:

[image: 'COMMANDLINE']

`COMMAND` table:

[image: <code>COMMAND</code>]

Only these 2 are needed to resolve the problem. I added the other just for more information.

**Sample output:**

To be honest, I'm not sure if both outputs are supposed to be "output" at the same time or that I need 2 `VIEWS` for each output.

[image: OUTPUT]

**WHAT HAVE I DONE SO FAR:**

I looked through what I could find on StackOverflow about `MAX` of `SUM`, but unfortunately, it has not helped me much in this case. I always seem to be doing something wrong.

I also found out that in order to use `ORDER BY` in `VIEWS` you need to, in this case, use `TOP`, but I've no idea how to apply it correctly when I need to select all of the `COMMANDLINES`. In one of my previous things, I used the following `SELECT TOP`:

```
create view PRODUCTS_BY_TYPE
as
    select top (select count(*) from ARTICLE 
                where CURRENT_QTT > MINIMUM_QTT)*
    from 
        ARTICLE
    order by 
        TYPE
```

This allowed me to show all `PRODUCT` data where the `CURRENT_QTT` was more than the minimum ordering them by type, but I can't figure out for the life of me, how to apply this to my current situation.

I could start with something like this:

```
create view THE_BEST
as
    select COMMANDLINE.*
    from COMMANDLINE
```

But then I don't know how to apply the `TOP`.

I figured that first, I need to see who the best client is, by `SUM`-ing all of the `PRICE` under his ID and then doing a `MAX` on all of the `SUM` of all clients.

So far, the best I could come up with is this:

```
create view THE_BEST
as
    select top (select count(*) 
                from (select max(max_price) 
                      from (select sum(PRICE) as max_price 
                            from COMMAND) COMMAND) COMMAND) COMMANDLINE.*
    from COMMANDLINE
    inner join COMMAND on COMMANDLINE.ID_COMMAND = COMMAND.ID_COMMAND
    order by COMMAND.ID_COMMAND desc, COMMANDLINE.ID_LINE asc
```

Unfortunately, in the `select count(*)` the `COMMAND` is underlined in red (a.k.a. the 3rd `COMMAND` word) and it says that there is "no column specified for column 1 of `COMMAND`".

EDIT:

I've come up with something closer to what I want:

```
create view THE_BEST
    as
        select top (select count(*) 
                    from (select max(total_price) as MaxPrice 
                          from (select sum(PRICE) as total_price 
                                from COMMAND) COMMAND) COMMAND)*
        from COMMANDLINE
        order by ID_LINE asc
```

Still missing the ordered by `ID_COMMAND` and I only get 1 result in the output when it should be 2.

Comment: can you please share some sample data and expected results as dml

Comment: @TheGameiswar Just edited the main question.

Comment: Please add your sample data as text values that can be copied and pasted.  We do not have the time to manually copy out your data from an image.

Answer (score 0):

here is some code that hopefully will show you how you can use the top-clause and also a different approche to show only the "top" :-)

```
/* Creating Tables*/
CREATE TABLE ARTICLE (ID_ARTICLE int,DES varchar(10),NAME varchar(10),PRICE float,TYPE int,CURRENT_QTT int,MINIMUM_QTT int)
CREATE TABLE COMMANDLINES (ID_LINE int,ID_COMMAND int,ID_ARTICLE  int,QUANTITY int)
CREATE TABLE COMMAND (ID_COMMAND int, ID_CLIENT varchar(20), PRICE float, PRINTED int)
CREATE TABLE CLIENT (ID_CLIENT varchar(20), FULL_NAME varchar(50), SSN varchar(50), PH_NUM varchar(50), MOBILE varchar(50), USERNAME varchar(50), PASSWORD varchar(50))

INSERT INTO COMMANDLINES VALUES (1,1,10,20),(2,1,12,3),(3,1,2,21),(1,2,30,2),(2,2,21,5),(1,3,32,20),(2,3,21,2)
INSERT INTO COMMAND VALUES (1,'1695152D',1200,0),(2,'1695152D',500,0),(3,'2658492D',200,0)
INSERT INTO ARTICLE VALUES(1, 'A','AA',1300,0,10,5),(2,'B','BB',450,0,10,5),(30,'C','CC',1000,0,5,5),(21,'D','DD',1500,0,5,5),(32,'E','EE',1600,1,4,5),(3,'F','FF',210,2,15,5)
INSERT INTO CLIENT VALUES ('1695152D', 'DoombringerBG', 'A','123','321','asdf','asf'),('2658492D', 'tgr', 'A','123','321','asdf','asf')
GO
/* Your View-Problem*/
CREATE VIEW PRODUCTS_BY_TYPE AS 
SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT *
FROM ARTICLE
WHERE CURRENT_QTT > MINIMUM_QTT -- You really don't want >= ??
ORDER BY [Type]
-- why do you need your view with an ordered output? cant your query order the data?
GO
```

OUTPUT:

```
ID_ARTICLE   | DES   | NAME  | PRICE | TYPE | CURRENT_QTT  | MINIMUM_QTT
-------------+-------+-------+-------+------+--------------+-------------
1            | A     | AA    | 1300  | 0    | 10           | 5
2            | B     | BB    | 450   | 0    | 10           | 5
3            | F     | FF    | 210   | 2    | 15           | 5
```

I hope this is what you were looking for :-)

```
-- your top customers
SELECT cli.FULL_NAME, SUM(c.PRICE)
FROM COMMANDLINES as cl
INNER JOIN COMMAND as c
on cl.ID_COMMAND = c.ID_COMMAND
INNER JOIN CLIENT as cli
on cli.ID_CLIENT = c.ID_CLIENT
GROUP BY cli.FULL_NAME
ORDER BY SUM(c.PRICE) DESC -- highest value first


SELECT * 
FROM (
    -- your top customers with a rank
    SELECT cli.FULL_NAME, SUM(c.PRICE) as Price, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SUM(c.PRICE) DESC) AS RowN
    FROM COMMANDLINES as cl
    INNER JOIN COMMAND as c
    on cl.ID_COMMAND = c.ID_COMMAND
    INNER JOIN CLIENT as cli
    on cli.ID_CLIENT = c.ID_CLIENT
    GROUP BY cli.FULL_NAME
) as a
-- only the best :-)
where RowN = 1 
--considerations: what if two customers have the same value?
```

Output:

```
FULL_NAME       |Price    | RowN
----------------+---------+-------
DoombringerBG   | 4600    | 1
```

Regards
tgr

===== EDITED =====

The syntax-corrention to your THE_BEST-View:

```
create view THE_BEST AS
SELECT TOP (
        SELECT count(*) as cnt
        FROM (
            SELECT max(max_price) as max_price
            FROM (
                SELECT sum(PRICE) AS max_price
                FROM COMMAND
                ) COMMAND
            ) COMMAND
        ) 
        cl.*
FROM COMMANDLINES  as  cl
INNER JOIN COMMAND as c
    ON cl.ID_COMMAND = c.ID_COMMAND
ORDER BY c.ID_COMMAND DESC
    ,cl.ID_LINE ASC
```

Without the `OVER`-Clause:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * 
FROM (
    -- your top customers with a rank
    SELECT cli.FULL_NAME, SUM(c.PRICE) as Price
    FROM COMMANDLINES as cl
    INNER JOIN COMMAND as c
    on cl.ID_COMMAND = c.ID_COMMAND
    INNER JOIN CLIENT as cli
    on cli.ID_CLIENT = c.ID_CLIENT
    GROUP BY cli.FULL_NAME
) as a
-- only the best :-)
ORDER BY Price DESC
```

Your PRODUCTS_BY_TYPE without PERCENT:

```
CREATE VIEW PRODUCTS_BY_TYPE AS 
SELECT TOP (select 
SUM(p.rows)
from sys.partitions as p
inner join sys.all_objects as ao
on p.object_id = ao.object_id
where ao.name = 'ARTICLE'
and ao.type = 'U')
*
FROM ARTICLE
WHERE CURRENT_QTT > MINIMUM_QTT -- You really don't want >= ??
ORDER BY [Type]
go
```

but to be honest - i would never use such a query in production... i only posted this because you need it for studing purposes...

Comment: First of all, thank you immensely about putting of this time into writing this.

Second of all, I read that it's not a very good idea to use `TOP 100 PERCENT` post SQL Server 2005.

Thirdly, I was actually told to use the `top (select count(*))...` for that case by a teacher.

Fourthly, I'm not allowed to use the `OVER` clause as it's not been officially explained. I'm also pretty sure it can be done without it as well.

And last but not least, I was considering the case where I might have two or more customers with the same value, it's why I'm trying to do it with `TOP (select...)`.

Comment: I also tried getting and counting the duplicates like [this here shows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2594829/finding-duplicate-values-in-a-sql-table), but no luck.

Comment: if two people have the same amount there still be a problem, because your top will be random. to see what i mean try this: SELECT TOP 1  * FROM (select  top 2 * from (select 1 as a, 'a' as t union all select 1, 'b' as a) as a order by newid()) as a order by a    1: I generate two rows, 2: is sort them by random 3: i select the first one sorted by column "a". the result vary sometimes -> i think you dont want this in your code

Comment: It's actually why I have the `select count(*)` right after `select top (....)` in the parenthesis, in case I have more than one result with the same value instead of using "TOP 1".

Thank you, your syntax correction actually made my original `View` work, but it's only showing one result. I'm assuming it's doing that because, obviously, there's only 1 max value.

I do apologize you having to write all of that, regardless it all help understanding some things.

Comment: Here's another example that would require me to do the same thing as in the original post: let's suppose I have a few airports in a table; each airport has a number of planes and some other data; I need to create a function which shows all of the data of all airports that have a number of planes equal or greater than the number introduced by the user. The information about the whereabouts of each plane is stored in another table called Planes, for example. <-- This requires pretty much the same main part of the solution.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite likely that there is some misunderstanding between you and your teacher. You can technically have `ORDER BY` clause in a view definition, but it never guarantees any order of the rows in the query that uses the view, such as `SELECT ... FROM your_view`. Without `ORDER BY` in the final `SELECT` the order of the result set is not defined. The order of rows returned to the client by the server is determined only by the final  outermost `ORDER BY` of the query, not by the `ORDER BY` in the view definition.

The purpose of having `TOP` in the view definition is to limit the number of returned rows somehow. For example, `TOP (1)`. In this case `ORDER BY` specifies which row(s) to return.

Having `TOP 100 PERCENT` in a view does nothing. It doesn't reduce the number of returned rows and it doesn't guarantee any specific order of returned rows.

---

Having said all that, in your case you need to find one best client, so it makes sense to use `TOP (1)` in a sub-query.

This query would return the ID of the best client:

```
SELECT 
    TOP (1) 
    -- WITH TIES
    ID_CLIENT
FROM COMMAND
GROUP BY ID_CLIENT
ORDER BY SUM(PRICE) DESC
```

If there can be several clients with the same maximum total price and you want to return data related to all of them, not just one random client, then use `TOP WITH TIES`.

Finally, you need to return lines that correspond to the chosen client(s):

```
create view THE_BEST
as
    SELECT
        COMMANDLINE.ID_LINE
        ,COMMANDLINE.ID_COMMAND
        ,COMMANDLINE.ID_ARTICLE
        ,COMMANDLINE.QUANTITY
    FROM
        COMMANDLINE
        INNER JOIN COMMAND ON COMMAND.ID_COMMAND = COMMANDLINE.ID_COMMAND
    WHERE
        COMMAND.ID_CLIENT IN
        (
            SELECT 
                TOP (1) 
                -- WITH TIES
                ID_CLIENT
            FROM COMMAND
            GROUP BY ID_CLIENT
            ORDER BY SUM(PRICE) DESC
        )
;
```

This is how the view can be used:

```
SELECT
    ID_LINE
    ,ID_COMMAND
    ,ID_ARTICLE
    ,QUANTITY
FROM THE_BEST
ORDER BY ID_COMMAND DESC, ID_LINE ASC;
```

Note, that `ORDER BY ID_COMMAND DESC, ID_LINE ASC` has to be in the actual query, not in the view definition.

Comment: You're probably right about the misunderstanding, but as for the `WITH TIES` clause, I can not use it as it's not been explained officially. I know it can be done with `select top(select count(*)....)` to limit the results till I get the proper ones, but I can't find out how. I spent another few hours on this again today and nothing. :S

Comment: @DoombringerBG, so, you do want to fetch all clients if there is tie, but you "can't" use the `WITH TIES` clause because your teacher doesn't accept the idea that students can read MSDN on their own. Interesting. Good luck with your teacher. I thinks it is possible to get the desired results without using the `WITH TIES` clause, but I'd like you to adjust your sample data and expected results in the question first. Please build your sample data in such a way that it includes all relevant edge cases. A side note: the idea of putting a sub-query inside the `TOP` looks strange to me.