# Return only duplicate values from table

Tags: sql, database, h2db

I am new to sql and I am facing a problem.
I have a table of call records which contains two columns `Anumber` and `Bnumber`. If any number calls, a new row is added to the table with Anumber as Source and Bnumber as Destination.

I have given two Anumber values `(3217913664,3006307180)` Now I have to find all the values from Bnumber (which was called by Anumber)

Let's say my table is :

```
ANUMBER        BNUMBER
-------        --------
3217913664     3006307180
3217913664     3212026005
3006307180     3212026005
3006307180     3212026007
3006307180     3212026008
3006307180     3212026009
3217913664     3212026009
```

Now I want to extract `value(3212026005 and 3212026009)` from Bnumber because both numbers were called by the given numbers. So I basically I have to extract only those numbers which were called by all the given number.

My English is not so good but I think I explained my problem. Any idea how can I achieve this scenario?

Comment: Try using GROUP BY and COUNT.

Comment: I have tried this query `SELECT ANUMBER,BNUMBER FROM CDR WHERE ANUMBER = '3217913664' OR ANUMBER = '3006307180'  GROUP BY ANUMBER,BNUMBER HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 ` But it doesnt give me the required results

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding duplicate values in a SQL table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2594829/finding-duplicate-values-in-a-sql-table)

Comment: No, its not possible duplicate

Comment: what makes this unique? take a look at the link

Comment: Yes, I have seen the link. But the query given in that answer doesn't give me the required result.

Comment: then you probably need to explain your problem more clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one method:

```
select bnumber
from t
where anumber in (3217913664, 3006307180)
group by bnumber
having min(anumber) < max(anumber);
```

If the rows have no duplicates, then using `count(*) = 2` is an alternative.

If you have more than 2 `anumber`s that you want to test, then use `count(distinct anumber) = n`, where `n` is the number of values in the `in` list.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one:

```
select  Bnumber
from    yourtable
group by Bnumber
having COUNT(Bnumber) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Anumber FROM yourtable) AS T)
```

this is a generic one. If you insert another Anumber in your table the query still works. 
Just one warning: Maybe this is not the best way to solve your problem, but I can't think in other query right now. Maybe later I would try to optimize the query.