# Golang gorm find return the two duplicate data

Tags: go, go-gorm

```
gorm.DB.Where("id in (?)", IDs).Find(&us)
```

If my IDs is `[]int{1,1}` and I want to return the two duplicate data，How can I do?
In my project if the IDs is `[]int{1,1}` it only return to me one data

Comment: But since it’s duplicated, you can use a  db.Where(“id = ?”, 1).find(&us) . If the “id” is a primary key, you can use db.Where(IDs).find(&us).

Comment: Could you tell us more context and data examples ? This might help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2594829/finding-duplicate-values-in-a-sql-table