# Find duplicates in two columns in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I just browse this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2594829/finding-duplicate-values-in-a-sql-table) and tried all the scripts but still i am not getting what i am expecting.

Here is my table

```
Name        email
BRIAN MAT   BRIAN.MAT@abc.Com
BRIAN MAT   BRIAN MAT@abc.Com
AMY Lee     AMY.Lee@abc.Com
AMY.Lee     AMY.Lee@abc.Com
Madison Taylor  Madison.Tyl@abc.com


SELECT Name 
FROM Employee
GROUP BY Name 
HAVING ( COUNT(Name > 1 )
```

result

BRIAN MAT

```
SELECT email
FROM Employee
GROUP BY email
HAVING ( COUNT(email> 1 )
```

Result

AMY.Lee@abc.Com

I was trying to group this two script but it shows blank

```
SELECT
    Name, email,COUNT(*)
FROM
    Employee
GROUP BY
    Name, email
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) > 1
```

Please correct me what i am missing in my script to acheive the result like below

```
Name        email
BRIAN MAT   BRIAN.MAT@abc.Com
BRIAN MAT   BRIAN MAT@abc.Com
AMY Lee     AMY.Lee@abc.Com
AMY.Lee     AMY.Lee@abc.Com
```

Comment: Grouping by both name and email will mean when name and email are both the same then return the result.  Either do this as a union (first query union all second query) or create subqueries (as per Juan Carlos's answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM Employee
WHERE Name IN (SELECT Name 
               FROM Employee
               GROUP BY Name 
               HAVING COUNT(Name > 1) 
              )
   OR Email IN (SELECT email
                FROM Employee
                GROUP BY email
                HAVING COUNT(email> 1)
              )
```

Comment: Thank you Juan, i was clueless how to get the expected result

Answer (score 3):

You could use windowed `COUNT`:

```
WITH cte  AS (
   SELECT *,
         COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY name)  AS c_name,
         COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY Email) AS c_email
   FROM Employee
)
SELECT name, email
FROM cte
WHERE c_name > 1 OR c_email > 1;
```

Comment: i was curious how the script work and i tried it but "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'AMY.LEE@abc.com' to data type int.

Comment: @Usher c_name or c_email are aliases for COUNT which returns number. Are you sure that you don't use something like `name > 1`?

Answer (score 1):

The least complicated. A quick and dirty solution.

```
SELECT 
    a.name, 
    a.email, count(*)
FROM
    employee a

INNER JOIN
    employee b on b.name = a.name or b.email = a.email
GROUP BY a.name, a.email
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```