# SQL- Gap analysis of the two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables with following values:

> User Name;User Number;Position No; Position Desc;Role;Role Description;User Type;User Lock Status;End Date; Single or Composite;Start Date; End Date; Date;Time.

I want to compare both the tables and would like the query to display only

> Name;User Number;Position No; Position Desc;Role;Role Description;User Type;User Lock Status;End Date; Single or Composite;Start Date; End Date; Date;Time.

For  User Number IF the value in 'Role' is different.

Comment: did you try anything?  this is an easy join

Comment: Can you write a query that returns the rows from table `one` no matter what rows are contained in table `two`? Do you have *any* SQL written? Do you realize that the SQL statement will start with `SELECT` keyword and include a `FROM` clause?  This question doesn't show much effort in terms of developing a query, showing example data, or expected output.  Not much of a specification other than listing some names of columns in some tables that we are left to guess at ... table "one" and table "two"? https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding duplicate values in a SQL table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2594829/finding-duplicate-values-in-a-sql-table)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    [whatever columns you want]
FROM
    Table1
    INNER JOIN Table1 ON Table1.UserNumber = Table2.UserNumber
WHERE
    Table1.Role != Table2.Role
```