# only do not select duplicated values mysql?

Tags: mysql, database

I am looking for a way to run a simple SELECT statment. I have a table which has two columns: id and email.

I want to run a SELECT statment that won't return duplicate values. For example, take the following data:

```
1   example@hotmail.com  
2   example12@hotmail.com  
3   example@hotmail.com 
4   example@hotmail.com
```

I want it to return only the following:

```
2   example12@hotmail.com
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding duplicate values in a SQL table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2594829/finding-duplicate-values-in-a-sql-table)

Answer (score 2):

Use aggregation `count(*)` and check the result of aggregate function using having clause to filter out those records which are not duplicated

```
select *
from demo
group by email
having count(*) = 1
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d9e797/1)

Comment: it give me like this #1055 - Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'users.prov.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Comment: @MømĕnẶłmĦsĕĕrỷ change * to email only

Answer (score 0):

select id,email from table group by email having count(*) =1;

Comment: it give me like this 
#1055 - Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'users.prov.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Comment: @MømĕnẶłmĦsĕĕrỷ which MySQL version are you using?