# SQL query to fetch duplicates

Tags: sql

I have the following table

```
people
person_id
first_name
last_name
```

I want to fetch all the people whose last names occur more than once.
Can someone help me with this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding duplicate values in a SQL table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2594829/finding-duplicate-values-in-a-sql-table)

Comment: You have too much reputation to be asking such poor questions. Where is your research? what have you tried? Why didn't you even use the tag for your RDBMS?

Answer (score 0):

SELECT

Person_id,
Last_Name,

First_Name,

COUNT(*)

FROM

```
People
```

GROUP BY

```
Person_id,Last_Name,First_Name
```

HAVING

```
COUNT(*) > 1
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Select *
from persons t1
Join (select t2t1. lastName, count(t2t1. *) 'counted' 
          from persons t2t1
          Group by t2t1. lastName
          Having count(t2t1. *) >1
     ) t2 on t1.LastName=t2. Lastname
```