# Finding duplicate rows in SQL table issue

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that has duplicate data. A field in the table has some typo's so I am trying to find all the rows in this table where the other column does not have the same information.

For example

**partnumber**

```
warehouse   int_pn    ext_pn
=========   ======    ======
1           ABC100    XYZ001
2           ABC100    XYZ001
1           ABC200    XYZ021
2           ABC200    XYY021
3           ABC999    XYZ999
```

In the table above, *int_pn* ABC200 exists in two warehouses (1 and 2) but in *ext_pn* for warehouse 2 there is a typo

I am trying to list all the rows where *int_pn* appears more than once but have a different *ext_pn*

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/96248d/1

The result of a query should return

**result**

```
warehouse   int_pn    ext_pn
=========   ======    ======
1           ABC200    XYZ021
2           ABC200    XYY021
```

I am having a hard time building a SQL query to do this

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding duplicate values in a SQL table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2594829/finding-duplicate-values-in-a-sql-table)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by self-join

```
SELECT p1.warehouse
    ,p1.int_pn
    ,p1.ext_pn
FROM partnumber AS p1
INNER JOIN partnumber AS p2 ON p1.int_pn = p2.int_pn
    AND p1.ext_pn != p2.ext_pn
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/96248d/28

Comment: Thank you - I was heading in this direction but could not work it out

Comment: if you have more than 2 lines with he same int_pn, rows will be multiplicated. You can avoid this with the `distinct` keyword

Answer (score 0):

You can group data by int_pn and then count the distinct values of  ext_pn

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/96248d/29

```
select warehouse, int_pn, ext_pn
from partnumber 
where int_pn in (
   select int_pn 
from partnumber
group by int_pn
having count(distinct ext_pn) >1)
```