# traversing the records in sql

Tags: sql, teradata

I would like to get the  output for the over lapping date records

```
> Data: Id Open_date Closed_Date
>       1  2016-01-01 2017-01-01
**>       1  2016-12-31 2018-21-01
>       1  2016-01-01 2018-01-01**
>       2  2017-01-01 2018-02-02
Here, you see the second & 3rd records are starting with date than the closed_Date of their previous records. Here i need to identify those type of records
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2594829/finding-duplicate-values-in-a-sql-table

Comment: Primary key is supposed to be unique

Comment: let's not consider Id as primary key column..slight correction

Comment: Search for the infamous Gap and Islands problem (tons of solutions online), and tag which DBMS are you using.

Comment: Hi Ezlo..sure!...Teradata i'm using

Answer (score 0):

As you question is not much clear, I am assuming that you are looking for min of open date and max of close date.
If this is not the requirement edit the question to provide more details.

```
select id, min(Open_date), max(Closed_Date)
from table
group by id
```

Comment: Edited the question!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to normalize a *Slowly Changing Dimension Type 2*. Of course the best way to handle them would be using *Temporal* tables using either Teradata or ANSI syntax.

There's a nice syntax in Teradata to get your expected result based on the Period data type, but it's imple to cast your begin/end dates to a period:

```
SELECT id,
   -- split the period back into seperate dates
   Begin(pd) AS Open_date,
   End(pd) AS Closed_Date
FROM
 (
   SELECT NORMALIZE -- magic keyword :-)
      id, PERIOD(Open_date, Closed_Date) AS pd
   FROM tab
 ) AS dt
```