# How can I get records that have a duplicate combination of columns in SQL?

Tags: sql

How can I get just the records that have a duplicate combination of columns? For example in the table below I want to get the records that have a duplicate combination of ParentID and Date.

```
+----+----------+-------------------------+
| ID | ParentID |          Date           |
+----+----------+-------------------------+
|  1 |      225 | 2018-05-10 00:00:00.000 |
|  2 |      225 | 2018-05-10 00:00:00.000 |
|  3 |      300 | 2019-25-11 00:00:00.000 |
+----+----------+-------------------------+
```

Comment: Surely you've tried a query already?

Comment: This question was asked a billion times on this site https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2594829/finding-duplicate-values-in-a-sql-table

Comment: Also, which database are you using?

Comment: Add some more sample data, and also specify the expected result.

Comment: @Nerevar - perhaps I wasn't using the right words to search! This is exactly what I wanted. Thanks!

Comment: What flavour of SQL are you using?

Answer (score 2):

The inner select gets the `parentID` and `date` of the records having duplicates and the outer select gets the cpmplete data including `id`

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM your_table t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT parentId, date
    FROM your_table
    GROUP BY parentId, date
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) t2
    ON t1.parentId = t2.parentId AND t1.date = t2.date;
```

Answer (score 1):

The MySQL answer to this question was given by @juergen but here is an option for any database supporting analytic functions:

```
SELECT ID, ParentID, Date
FROM
(
    SELECT ID, ParentID, Date, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY ParentID, Date) cnt
    FROM yourTable
) t
WHERE t.cnt > 1;
```

In general, the above approach using analytic functions would probably outperform the traditional join/aggregation approach.  But, this assumes that your database supports the above query.

Comment: Your answer seems to suggest, that MySQL does not support that. Is that really the case? I thought that MySQL 8.0.2 introduced window functions.

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann Yes, it does.  But few people are using this version in production (I don't even know if it's available e.g. via RDS).  Hence, most MySQL questions sort of assume the version is earlier than 8.

Comment: I would be delighted if you could rephrase your answer such that the hasty copy-reader defaults to analytic functions even when using MySQL. IMHO this is the better default case.