# MYSQL: How to get the count of each distinct value in a column for unique id

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, count

i'm new to Mysql and SO,let me know if my question is not clear

i have a table like this

```
key | value
-----------------------
key1  | value3
key1  | value3
key1  | value1
key3  | value4
key3  | value2
key4  | value1
key4  | value1
key5  | value2
```

i need count of each distinct value that matched with unique keys.

For EX:
i need o/p like

```
( 
 (key1,value1:1,value3:2),
 (key3,value2:1,value4:1),
 (key4,value1:2),
 (key5,value2:1,)
)
```

can anyone suggest me the query.

**Edit:** I used `group by` like

```
select value, count(*) from table GROUP BY value;
```

but it's not giving proper results.

Comment: So you need concatenated values for each grouped keys?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding duplicate values in a SQL table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2594829/finding-duplicate-values-in-a-sql-table)

Answer (score 0):

I just tested this query with the same table you gave and it gave the results you are asking for

```
SELECT key, value, COUNT(*)
FROM your_table
GROUP BY
key, value
HAVING 
COUNT(*) >= 1
ORDER BY key
```