# Having Count isnt working

Tags: sql, postgresql

Not sure what I did this morning but I must have hit my head really hard

Here is my query

```
select c.id as cid,c.studentid as cstudentid              
from certification c
group by c.id,c.studentid
order by c.studentid
```

My results are this

```
 cid studentid
 35267  6400
 5332   6401
 35271  6402
144024 6402
252727 6402
434317 6402
529734 6405
...
```

I want the student ids that are repeared more than twice like 6402

I tried the basic query like this

```
select c.id as cid,c.studentid as cstudentid              
from certification c
group by c.id,c.studentid
having count(c.studentid) > 2
order by c.studentid
```

the output is Empty/nothing/no table...

System: Postgres 9.3

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query doesn't do your expectations. It returns all rows with count of One on each row. Because you've grouped both of the columns. Also it can't find the related rows to aggregate. So you could change your query to group it by one column (c.studentId) and aggregate on another (c.id). It could be like this following code:

```
select count(c.id), c.studentid as cstudentid              
from certification c
group by c.studentid
having count(c.id) > 2
order by c.studentid
```

If you need the duplicated `c.id`'s  you should write a CTE query. The second answer of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2594829/finding-duplicate-values-in-a-sql-table) will help you.

Comment: actually your answer fixed everything!! The concept of your answer of aggregating a different field made the difference. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this: But, you should specify with the output:
Remove cid from group by as, from your table it seemed that cid is unique

```
select c.studentid as cstudentid              
from certification c
group by c.studentid
having count(c.studentid) > 2
order by c.studentid
```