# How select row where some column has more than 1 distinct value?

Tags: postgresql

I have to find if there are Rows where a `Name` has more than one distinct `Family`.

> Note: `Name` and `Family` can be duplicate.

```
ID      Name        Family
1       ABC         XYZ
2       DEF         XYZ
3       ABC         UVW
4       ABC         RST
5       DEF         RST
6       GHI         UVW
```

The expected Output should be

```
Name
ABC
DEF
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding duplicate values in a SQL table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2594829/finding-duplicate-values-in-a-sql-table)

Comment: I don't want to find duplicate rows, I want to find if a Name has more than one Family

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could do this;

```
SELECT Name, COUNT(DISTINCT Family)
FROM [table]
GROUP BY Name
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Family) > 1
```

Comment: better use an alias for "count (distinct Family)" and call "having" with that alias, for readability