# I want find duplicate data? and display duplicate records only?

Tags: mysql, duplicates

in my table having data like this

```
+-----+----------+  
| sno | name     |  
+-----+----------+  
| 101 | Raju     |  
| 102 | Raju     |  
| 103 | Santhosh |  
| 104 | Santhosh |  
| 105 | madhavi  |  
| 106 | suheel   |  
+-----+----------+
```

in that i want find dupliacte records and display sno(number) only
for example output should be like this

```
+-----+  
| sno |  
+-----+  
| 101 |  
| 102 |  
| 103 |  
| 104 |  
+-----+
```

Comment: Have you tried a query yet?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/2594829/3404097

Comment: This is a faq. Please always google error messages & many clear, concise & specific versions/phrasings of your question/problem/goal with & without your particular strings/names & 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags & read many answers. Add relevant keywords you discover to your searches. If you don't find an answer then post, using 1 variant search as title & keywords for tags. See the downvote arrow mouseover text. When you do have a non-duplicate code question to post please read & act on [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

In a Derived table, get all the `name` values which have duplicates. To do that, we can `GROUP BY` on `name` and use `HAVING` to consider only those names, where `COUNT(*)` (total number of rows for that `name`) is more than 1.

Now, we can join back to the main table to get their respective `sno` values

```
SELECT
 t.sno
FROM your_table t
JOIN (SELECT name 
      FROM your_table 
      GROUP BY name
      HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) dt
  ON dt.name = t.name
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a MySQL 8+ way of doing this:

```
SELECT sno
FROM
(
    SELECT t.*, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY name) cnt
    FROM yourTable t
) t
WHERE cnt > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using correlated subquery

```
select sno from tablename a 
where name in (select 1 from tablename b where a.name=b.name having count(name)>1 )
```