# How to find whether two attributes have 1:1 mapping in a given dataset using sql?

Tags: sql

I have the following data given, what I am trying to do is to find if the cardinality between name and id is 1:1

Sample Data:

```
Id   Name
1    ABC
2    PQR
1    XYZ
4    ABC
90   PQR
100  LMN
30   DEF
```

Example:
I want to detect the following problems:
1) Id "1" maps to more than one names ("ABC", LMN")
2) Name "PQR" corresponds to more than one Ids ("2", "90")
3) Name "ABC" corresponds to more than one Ids ("1", "4")

```
SELECT COUNT(Id) AS IdCount,
       Count(Name) AS NameCount
FROM InputData;
```

However, this will not tell me the answer I want, since there could be equal number of unique ids and names and still have more than one mapping among them.
I don't care about duplicates for eg. if "1" corresponds to "ABC" multiple times, that should be okay.

Comment: What variety of SQL are you using (MySQL, SQL-Server, Oracle etc.)?

Comment: Please make clear exactly what you want returned. You only say vague things like "detect the following problems". PS What does this have to do with relational algebra? (Other than what is implied by tagging with SQL.)

Comment: "I don't care about duplicates for eg. if "1" corresponds to "ABC" multiple times, that should be okay." You only have attributes `Id`, `Name`. Then if you have duplicate pairings that means duplicate tuples in the relation. Which means it's a bag, not a set. Which means it's not a relation. Which means you can't be talking about relational algebra. Neither could it be a SQL base table.

Comment: @AntC SQL base tables can have (SQL-)duplicate rows. Which I expect you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is the same as detecting duplicates in either column, in which case I'll adapt an answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2594855/13675).

Ids mapped to more than one Name:

```
SELECT
    Id, COUNT(*)
FROM
    InputData
GROUP BY
    Id
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) > 1
```

Names mapped to more than one Id:

```
SELECT
    Name, COUNT(*)
FROM
    InputData
GROUP BY
    Name
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way of doing it, using a `UNION` of two `SELECT`s, one which finds all the problem `Id` values and the other which finds the problem `Name` values:

```
SELECT 'Id' AS Type, CAST(Id AS CHAR) AS Problem
FROM InputData
GROUP BY Id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Name) > 1
UNION
SELECT 'Name', Name
FROM InputData
GROUP BY Name
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Id) > 1
```

Output

```
Type    Problem
Id      1
Name    ABC
Name    PQR
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9Wjh4PsMSJth1Tk2jj8i8S/1)

Answer (score 0):

Just simply do:

```
select (case when count(*) = count(distinct id) and
                  count(*) = count(distinct name)
             then '1-1'
             else 'Ooops'
        end)
from inputdata id;
```

In other words, the relationship is 1-1 if all the `id`s are distinct and all the `name`s are distinct.

If your data might contain "complete" duplicates, such as:

```
1  ABC
1  ABC
```

Then change the `from` clause to:

from (select distinct id, name from inputdata) id