# Select duplicate using partition by in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to select all duplicate from a table:

```
SELECT * FROM people HAVING (count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY name)) > 1;
```

Unfortunately I get the error:

```
Error Code: 3593. You cannot use the window function 'count' in this context.
```

One less elegant solution would be:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    people
WHERE
    code IN (SELECT 
            name
        FROM
            people
        GROUP BY name
        HAVING COUNT(*) > 1);
```

How can I rewrite my first query to make it work?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2594829/finding-duplicate-values-in-a-sql-table

Comment: @KrishnaKarthik Not really an answer to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `code` is identical then you can use `exists` :

```
select p.*
from people p 
where exists (select 1 from people p1 where p1.name = p.name and p.code <> p1.code);
```

Use identity column instead if `code` column doesn't have a identity feature if entire table has no any identity column then your method works fine with following updated query :

```
SELECT p.*
FROM people p
WHERE name IN (SELECT name FROM people GROUP BY name HAVING COUNT(*) > 1);
```

Comment: Well, I would like to use `PARTITION BY` as requested in the question

Comment: And, thus, avoid using two `SELECT` queries