# How to find number of times a values is repeated in a string in a column

Tags: sql, hana

In SQL HANA, I need to find how many times a given word is repeated in a string column whose values are delimited by "," and output it as a separate column.

Example, the string column contains:

```
ZN,ZN,ZS,ZQ
```

Expected result for "ZN":

```
2
```

Comment: which db engine? version?

Comment: @metal SAP HANA

Comment: You should handle such things in your program logic and not in SQL

Comment: i don't have  any program logic used, its completely  data base work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding duplicate values in a SQL table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2594829/finding-duplicate-values-in-a-sql-table)

Comment: You may need a split function, and apply a simple "count / group by" request on the result : for the split function,  see https://blogs.sap.com/2019/02/10/split-string-into-multiple-rows-using-sql-in-sap-hana/

Answer (score 1):

You might find it acceptable to search only the string `ZN` by ignoring the fact that there's a comma.

You may count the number of occurrences of any substring by using the [string function `OCCURRENCES_REGEXPR`](https://help.sap.com/viewer/4fe29514fd584807ac9f2a04f6754767/2.0.00/en-US/4114b026f750429c8eeef9f54258edfa.html):

```
SELECT OCCURRENCES_REGEXPR('(ZN)' IN STRINGCOLUMN) "occurrences_zn" FROM TABLE;
```

If you really want to clearly specify that ZN is to be searched as an entire word between commas or at the edges, then you may find a better regular expression (the question is then more about regular expressions and not SQL HANA, and you may find existing answers in Stack Overflow).

Answer (score 0):

I can't remember where I found the trick, but in SQL Server, the following works like a charm:

```
DECLARE @myStringToSearch nvarchar(250) = 'ZN,ZN,ZS,ZQ'
DECLARE @searchValue nvarchar(5) = 'ZN'

SELECT (LEN(@myStringToSearch) - LEN(REPLACE(@myStringToSearch, @searchValue, ''))) / LEN(@searchValue)
```

The last line compares the length of the original string with the length of the same string, but this time replacing your search value (`ZN`) with a blank string. In our case, this would result in 4, because ZN is 2 characters, and it was removed twice. However, we're not interested in how many characters were removed, but in how many times the value was encountered, so we divide that result by the length of your search string (2).

Output of the query:

```
2
```

You could easily implement this as a DEFAULT constraint in your table, provided your search string is the same across every row.

Answer (score -1):

I wrote one anonymous block  in sql , which can be converted to  HANA Table function and can be used to achieve expected result.

DO

BEGIN

DECLARE FULL_STRING VARCHAR(100);

DECLARE TRIM_STRING VARCHAR(100);

DECLARE VAL_STRING VARCHAR(100);

FULL_STRING ='ZN,ZN,ZS,ZQ';

FULL_STRING=CONCAT(FULL_STRING,',');

--SELECT :FULL_STRING FROM DUMMY;

VAL_STRING=SUBSTRING(:FULL_STRING,1,LOCATE(:FULL_STRING,',',1)-1);

VAR_TABLE=SELECT :VAL_STRING STRINGVAL FROM DUMMY;

TRIM_STRING=SUBSTRING(:FULL_STRING,LOCATE(:FULL_STRING,',',1)+1 ,LENGTH(:FULL_STRING));

--SELECT * FROM :VAR_TABLE;

--SELECT :TRIM_STRING FROM DUMMY;

WHILE :TRIM_STRING  IS NOT NULL  AND  LENGTH(:TRIM_STRING)>0

DO
VAL_STRING=SUBSTRING(:TRIM_STRING,1,LOCATE(:TRIM_STRING,',',1)-1);

--SELECT :VAL_STRING FROM DUMMY;

VAR_TABLE=SELECT  STRINGVAL FROM :VAR_TABLE
            UNION ALL
           SELECT :VAL_STRING FROM DUMMY;

TRIM_STRING=SUBSTRING(:TRIM_STRING,LOCATE(:TRIM_STRING,',',1)+1 ,LENGTH(:TRIM_STRING));
--i=i+1;

--SELECT :TRIM_STRING FROM DUMMY;

END WHILE ;

SELECT STRINGVAL,COUNT(STRINGVAL) FROM :VAR_TABLE GROUP BY STRINGVAL;

--SELECT :TRIM_STRING FROM DUMMY;