# How do I find a duplicate in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a query that selects 3 columns. Each row row **should** be a unique combination of county, city,and zip. However, I have reason to believe I'm getting a duplicate somewhere. How do I find the duplicate ? COUNT() ?? This in MS SQL Server . Any help would be most appreciated. --Jason

```
SELECT  COUNTY, CITY, ZIP 
FROM MoratoriumLocations
WHERE MoratoriumID=20
ORDER BY County
```

Comment: Group by County, city, zip should give you a unique combination.

Comment: check this answer might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2594829/finding-duplicate-values-in-a-sql-table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You coul use `group by` and `having`

```
SELECT  COUNTY, CITY, ZIP 
FROM MoratoriumLocations
WHERE MoratoriumID=20
GROUP BY COUNTY, CITY, ZIP
HAVING COUNT(1) >1
ORDER BY County
```

If you want to get the full row details you can use a sub query in combination with the `group by` and `having` statements

```
SELECT x.*
FROM MoratoriumLocations x
INNER JOIN( 
  SELECT  COUNTY, CITY, ZIP 
  FROM MoratoriumLocations
  WHERE MoratoriumID=20
  GROUP BY COUNTY, CITY, ZIP
  HAVING COUNT(1) >1
) dups ON dups.County = x.County
  AND dups.City = x.City
  AND dups.Zip = x.Zip
```

Answer (score 0):

See Preben's answer for how to find dups.

To avoid dups altogether consider creating an **unique index**.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest window functions:

```
SELECT ml.*
FROM (SELECT ml.*, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY County, City, Zip) as cnt
      FROM MoratoriumLocations ml
      WHERE MoratoriumID = 20
     ) ml
ORDER BY cnt DESC, County, City, Zip;
```

This will show the complete rows with duplicates, which can help you understand them better.