# Inner Join query with two tables

Tags: sql, join

I am trying to work out a query where by it returns the employees who have not being assigned a job yet.

I've tried inner join query but it hasn't worked for me. Help is much appreciated on this :)

The two tables are as follows:

employee

```
•   id [varchar]
•   employee_name [varchar]
•   department [varchar]
```

job

```
•   id [varchar]
•   factory [varchar]
•   employee_name [varchar]
```

There is more dimensions in these two tables but iv only included the relevant ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Left joins` return all data including `nulls` (where this is no data to be had)

Use that over an `inner join`.

```
Select e.* from employee e -- Select only the data from the employee table (that's all we care about)
left join job j on e.employee_name = j.employee_name -- This will return all employee data no matter if they have a job or not
where j.id is null -- We are looking for employees that have no job currently
```

[image: SQL Join explanation]

Comment: Great this has worked great !! Dont know why i didnt use left join course it makes sense now.

Comment: I also have the employees "address" in the table. Is there an operand in SQL that selects all the employees with the same address. Rather than going about it a conventional way ?

Comment: You'd have to use the COUNT() function https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2594829/finding-duplicate-values-in-a-sql-table?rq=1

Comment: SELECT employee_name, address COUNT(*) as C FROM employee
group by address having COUNT(*) >1 order by C

Comment: something like this ?? or am i off the ball

Comment: SELECT e.employee_name, e.address
FROM employee e
INNER JOIN (SELECT address, COUNT(*)
FROM employee 
GROUP BY address
HAVING count(*) > 1 ) b
ON e.address = b.address
ORDER BY e.employee_name

Comment: Sorry for this but im also wondering on one more thing !! I have male (boolean), female (boolean) and country as dimensions also and im trying to retrieve which country has the second highest percentage of female workers. I tried getting the top which i think worked out but the second highest is troubling me.

Comment: yes it did and thanks, I marked it as correct im sure ? I actually replied to that also and didnt send so apologies