# SSIS Check Excel File Duplicate Values - Throw Error and dont insert to database

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a question about SSIS Load Excel Files.
I have an excel file with data, and I want if in excel file have duplicate values, stop the process, and don't insert to the database, throw an error and send mail.
If I have a unique record, insert it in the database.

Can you help me?

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Atnx6.png)

Comment: I would, initially, start at looking at `UNIQUE INDEX`es/`UNQIUE CONSTRAINT`s. Good luck!

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/2029983)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a primary key on your destination table and it'll behave as you desire.

Syntax of your SQL should look something like this:

```
ALTER TABLE TableName
ADD CONSTRAINT PK_TableName
PRIMARY KEY (ColumnName1,ColumnName2)
```

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_primarykey.ASP

To easy error handling implement an error handler where on error you move the duplicate row to an error table, saves you a lot of time searching for the duplicate row.

Comment: yes. i have a primary key on destination table, but i have a lookup ( i added a new  image on my post) and i must redirect rows to no match output to destination table. Can i check duplicate values in excel file or not?

Comment: You could do a different lookup first with no match on destination first where AND count > 2 and handle these first

Comment: Example of this step: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2594829/finding-duplicate-values-in-a-sql-table