# Try to count double entries in table

Tags: sql, mariadb

I try to count all double entries in a database table. I use a mariadb with myphpadmin.

If I use:

```
SELECT 
    cd1.*
FROM
    (SELECT 
        kunde,
            COUNT(DISTINCT kunde) AS counterkunde
    FROM
        bot_temp
    GROUP BY kunde) AS cd2,
    bot_temp cd1
WHERE
    cd2.counterkunde > 1
        AND cd1.kunde = cd2.kunde
ORDER BY cd1.kunde
```

I do not get any double entry. But I made some double entries to debug.
Table looks like

```
id | kunde | created_at
```

Any idea what is wrong in my SQL query?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding duplicate values in a SQL table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2594829/finding-duplicate-values-in-a-sql-table)

Comment: @Kevin, yes this helps a lot

Answer (score 0):

It's DISTINCT that eliminates all the duplicates on your query. Just remove it and try again

```
...
(SELECT kunde,
        COUNT(kunde) AS counterkunde
...
```

[db_fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=92881a6f5cda07c4108406c550c9664a)

Comment: this will result all entries

Comment: Hmm, I thought  that was the aim of your query. Anyway, you already have the  answer from the comments